# Find intersection of pairs of straight lines

Tags: graphics, geometry, intersection

I have a list of 24 points, in which two consecutive points (1st and 2nd, 3rd and 4th, …) are supposed to form a line:

```
p1={{243.8, 77.}, {467.4, 12.}, {291.8, 130.}, {476., 210.5}, {103.2, 
  327.}, {245.2, 110.5}, {47.4, 343.}, {87.4, 108.5}, {371., 
  506.5}, {384.6, 277.}, {264.6, 525.5}, {353.8, 294.5}, {113.2, 
  484.5}, {296., 304.5}, {459.6, 604.5}, {320.2, 466.5}, {288.2, 
  630.5}, {199.6, 446.5}, {138.8, 615.5}, {81.8, 410.}, {232.4, 
  795.}, {461.8, 727.}, {27.4, 671.5}, {206.8, 763.5}};
```

I also have another list of 24 points with the same property:

```
p2={{356.8, 32.}, {363.2, 120.}, {346., 245.}, {393.8, 158.}, {163.8, 
  211.5}, {230.2, 250.}, {54.6, 225.}, {139.6, 220.}, {366., 
  394.5}, {451.8, 372.}, {241., 398.}, {321., 411.5}, {163.2, 
  347.}, {213.2, 406.5}, {332.4, 596.5}, {402.4, 528.5}, {176., 
  585.5}, {256., 530.5}, {38.2, 553.}, {122.4, 507.}, {345.2, 
  774.5}, {345.2, 688.}, {104.6, 728.}, {161.8, 647.}};
```

My goal is to find the intersections between a line in `p1` and a line in `p2` as shown in the graph below. I really don't know how to start with this<s>, and worse, a line on `p1` does not match up with the intersecting line in `p2` in terms of order in each list. This could be observed by different colors of 2 intersecting lines, and makes it harder for element-by-element manipulation</s>*. How can I solve this?

```
Join[Partition[p1, 2], Partition[p2, 2]] // ListLinePlot
```

[image: Join Partition line intersection]

*I found out that this is thankfully not true, as seen below when line i in `p1` and line i in `p2` are plotted together, and also by Öskå in a comment to eldo's answer.

```
Row@Table[
  ListLinePlot[{Partition[p1, 2][[i]], Partition[p2, 2][[i]]}], {i, 1,
    Length@Partition[p1, 2]}]
```

[image: line pairs]

[image: lines]

Comment: In Wolfram Programming Cloud, and supposedly future Mathematica 10, you can find intersections using geometric computation: `{x, y} /. Solve[Apply[And, Element[{x, y}, Line[Partition[#, 2]]] & /@ {p1, p2}], {x, y}]`

Comment: @kirma Nice work!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
p1 = Partition[{{243.8, 77.}, {467.4, 12.}, {291.8, 130.}, {476., 
    210.5}, {103.2, 327.}, {245.2, 110.5}, {47.4, 343.}, {87.4, 
    108.5}, {371., 506.5}, {384.6, 277.}, {264.6, 525.5}, {353.8, 
    294.5}, {113.2, 484.5}, {296., 304.5}, {459.6, 604.5}, {320.2, 
    466.5}, {288.2, 630.5}, {199.6, 446.5}, {138.8, 615.5}, {81.8, 
    410.}, {232.4, 795.}, {461.8, 727.}, {27.4, 671.5}, {206.8, 
    763.5}}, 2];

p2 = Partition[{{356.8, 32.}, {363.2, 120.}, {346., 245.}, {393.8, 
     158.}, {163.8, 211.5}, {230.2, 250.}, {54.6, 225.}, {139.6, 
     220.}, {366., 394.5}, {451.8, 372.}, {241., 398.}, {321., 
     411.5}, {163.2, 347.}, {213.2, 406.5}, {332.4, 596.5}, {402.4, 
     528.5}, {176., 585.5}, {256., 530.5}, {38.2, 553.}, {122.4, 
     507.}, {345.2, 774.5}, {345.2, 688.}, {104.6, 728.}, {161.8, 
     647.}}, 2];

LineIntersectionPoint[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] := 
  (Det[{a, b}] (c - d) - Det[{c, d}] (a - b))/Det[{a - b, c - d}]

Graphics[{Line /@ {p1, p2}, Red, PointSize@.05, 
  Point /@ MapThread[LineIntersectionPoint, {p1, p2}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[Ref](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Line-LineIntersection.html) for finding intersection of 2 lines by determinants

[image: line graph]

[image: determinant intersection]

Comment: @Öskå - thanks for your elegant edit. With the too complicated "line production" I wanted to verify for myself that the lines cross pairwise in ascending order, because the OP suggested that "line on p1 does not match up with the intersecting line in p2 in terms of order in each list." Probably he was distracted by the coloring of `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: I guess so :) Using `Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line /@ {p1, p2}, Red, Line /@ {p1[[i]], p2[[i]]}}], {i, 1, Length@p1, 1}]` helps to see that intersect with each others :)

Comment: nice with and without edit +1

Comment: I don't believe this is sufficient if we believe the OP when he writes "... and worse, a line on p1 does not match up with the intersecting line in p2 in terms of order in each list."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I'm afraid I don't see your point. All answers (except the very interesting last answer given by George....) agree with the graphical representation of the question. Please clarify where the insufficiency occurs.

Comment: I mean that if you randomize the order of the line segments in either `p1` or `p2` (or both) this breaks, yet based on what the OP wrote a valid solution must work in that case despite the fact that his example is an easier problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I hesitantly agree. But the randomisation is pretty well covered with the answer of george2079 (I just upvoted it thanks to your consideration)

Comment: I was fooled by the coloring of ListLinePlot like @eldo wisely pointed out. Therefore, I think eldo's answer best fit my situation, although I think several of the other answers do address the non-matching cases.

Comment: I edited your code to make it somewhat cleaner.  You could also use `LineIntersectionPoint[p_, q_] := (Det[p] #2 - Det[q] #)/Det[{#, #2}] & @@ Subtract @@@ {p, q}` which is more terse and eliminates redundant subtraction, but it is of a significantly different style so I didn't substitute it.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mr.Wizard for the MapThread edit. I was actually kinda intimidated by eldo's implementation of LineIntersectionPoint at first so I thought I could try MapThread instead (which worked) and I was pleasantly surprised that you also used MapThread. I'm slowly but surely learning MMA.

Answer (score 18):

Turning my comment into an answer per (now deleted?) comment which requested it.

This is documented to work only in Wolfram Language at this point (specifically Wolfram Programming Cloud). Interestingly enough, it **does** work also with Mathematica 9.0.1., although documentation has no indication of `Line` or `Solve` supporting geometric regions.

```
p1 = {{243.8, 77.}, {467.4, 12.}, {291.8, 130.}, {476., 
       210.5}, {103.2, 327.}, {245.2, 110.5}, {47.4, 343.}, {87.4, 
       108.5}, {371., 506.5}, {384.6, 277.}, {264.6, 525.5}, {353.8, 
       294.5}, {113.2, 484.5}, {296., 304.5}, {459.6, 604.5}, {320.2, 
       466.5}, {288.2, 630.5}, {199.6, 446.5}, {138.8, 615.5}, {81.8, 
       410.}, {232.4, 795.}, {461.8, 727.}, {27.4, 671.5}, {206.8, 
       763.5}};

p2 = {{356.8, 32.}, {363.2, 120.}, {346., 245.}, {393.8, 
       158.}, {163.8, 211.5}, {230.2, 250.}, {54.6, 225.}, {139.6, 
       220.}, {366., 394.5}, {451.8, 372.}, {241., 398.}, {321., 
       411.5}, {163.2, 347.}, {213.2, 406.5}, {332.4, 596.5}, {402.4, 
       528.5}, {176., 585.5}, {256., 530.5}, {38.2, 553.}, {122.4, 
       507.}, {345.2, 774.5}, {345.2, 688.}, {104.6, 728.}, {161.8, 
       647.}};

(* Convert coordinate-lists to two collections of lines which can be used as
   primitives in both in graphics and new geometric computation. *)
{lines1, lines2} = Line[Partition[#, 2]]& /@ {p1, p2};

(* Create points which belong to both geometric regions
   consisting of line collections, that is any intersections. *)
points = Point[{x, y}] /. Solve[{x, y} \[Element] lines1 &&
                                {x, y} \[Element] lines2, {x, y}];

(* Represent all these as Graphics. *)
Graphics[{Blue, lines1, Red, lines2,
          Black, PointSize[Large], points}, Frame->True]
```

> [image]

**EDIT**:

You can also write above `Solve`in v10 as:

```
Solve[{x, y} \[Element] RegionIntersection[lines1, lines2], {x, y}]
```

This gets interesting when you consider the fact these regions can be much more than lines, for instance circles, filled regions such as disks, implicit and parametric regions, and derived regions. Also in higher dimensions, and symbolically. And they can be discretized, among other things for use of FEM in v10.

Comment: It can work in MMA 9.0.1 and your comment still  exist.

Comment: @Chenminqi This is interesting. `Line` definitely has no documentation hinting of that. Is it undocumented beginnings of geometric region computation?

Comment: @kirma exciting !!!

Comment: Whoa - how did you come across this one?

Comment: @YvesKlett See "Geometric computation" in Wolfram Language documentation. I have been playing with it on Programming Cloud which was unveiled yesterday. Finding out it works with 9.0.1 is entirely thanks to Chenminqi. :)

Comment: +1 I deleted my request comment because it contained stuff that's not so relevant to others except you personally. TY for the proper answer.

Comment: @joojaa No problem. :)

Answer (score 16):

Here is a direct vector calculation that verifies the segments (not just the infinite lines) intersect.

```
 segsegintersection[ lines_ ] := Module[{
    md = Subtract @@ (Plus @@ # & /@ lines),
    sub = Subtract @@ # & /@ lines, det},
        det = -Det[sub];
        If[And @@ (Abs[#] <= 1 & /@ #) ,
             (Plus @@ #[[1]] - Subtract @@ #[[1]] Last@#[[2]])/2 & @
               {First@lines, # }, False] &@
               (Det[{#[[1]], md}]/det & /@ ( {#, Reverse@#}  &@ sub))];
```

in the example provided they all intersect.. but I thought it useful to included here for completeness. This is *way* faster than using `Solve` with constraints. Note @eldo's `LineIntersectionPoint` is faster than this by a factor of 2 if you do not need the intersection check.

```
  Graphics[ {Line /@ p1  , Line /@ p2 , Red, PointSize[.025],
      Point@ MapThread[segsegintersection[{ #1 , #2 }] & , {p1, p2} ]}]
```

> same plot as the others..

An example with only some intersections:

```
 lines = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2, 2}];
 Graphics[{Line@lines, Red, PointSize[.02], 
      Point@Select[ segsegintersection[#] & /@ 
              Subsets[lines, {2}] ,  # =!= False &]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As I noted in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13714), there is a built-in, but undocumented function that can do this:

```
p1 = Partition[{{243.8, 77.}, {467.4, 12.}, {291.8, 130.}, {476., 210.5}, {103.2, 327.},
                {245.2, 110.5}, {47.4, 343.}, {87.4, 108.5}, {371., 506.5}, {384.6, 277.},
                {264.6, 525.5}, {353.8, 294.5}, {113.2, 484.5}, {296., 304.5},
                {459.6, 604.5}, {320.2, 466.5}, {288.2, 630.5}, {199.6, 446.5},
                {138.8, 615.5}, {81.8, 410.}, {232.4, 795.}, {461.8, 727.}, {27.4, 671.5},
                {206.8, 763.5}}, 2];

p2 = Partition[{{356.8, 32.}, {363.2, 120.}, {346., 245.}, {393.8, 158.}, {163.8, 211.5},
                {230.2, 250.}, {54.6, 225.}, {139.6, 220.}, {366., 394.5}, {451.8, 372.},
                {241., 398.}, {321., 411.5}, {163.2, 347.}, {213.2, 406.5}, {332.4, 596.5},
                {402.4, 528.5}, {176., 585.5}, {256., 530.5}, {38.2, 553.}, {122.4, 507.},
                {345.2, 774.5}, {345.2, 688.}, {104.6, 728.}, {161.8, 647.}}, 2];

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
pts = Flatten[MapThread[FindIntersections[{Line[#1], Line[#2]}] &, {p1, p2}], 1];

Graphics[{{Red, Line[p1]}, {Blue, Line[p2]}, {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pts]}}]
```

[image: intersecting lines]

---

The method in eldo's answer will work only in two dimensions. Additionally, due to its determinantal form (Cramer's rule), it can suffer from instability for certain special configurations. Thus, it is profitable to recast the formula used as an explicit linear least squares problem that can be dealt with by `LeastSquares[]`, as well as reformulating it so that it makes no assumptions on the dimensions of the given endpoints. Thus:

```
lineIntersection[Line[{p1_, p2_}], Line[{q1_, q2_}]] :=
    With[{sol = LeastSquares[Transpose[{p2 - p1, q2 - q1}], q1 - p1]},
         {p1 + sol[[1]] (p2 - p1), q1 - sol[[2]] (q2 - q1)}]
```

This returns a list of two points. In two dimensions, the two points are identical, and this is the unique point of intersection:

```
pts == MapThread[lineIntersection[Line[#1], Line[#2]][[1]] &, {p1, p2}]
   True
```

In three dimensions (and beyond!), if the two lines do intersect, the two points should be identical. If the two lines are in fact skew lines, the two points returned will be different, and these are the points of closest approach in each of the two lines.

(N.B. The previous version of this answer used a formulation equivalent to the normal equations, which can also fail in some cases. The current version should now be quite robust.)

Comment: It should probably be noted that in fact, `lineIntersection[]` does not at all depend on the dimensions of the points contained within the `Line[]` objects given to it.

Answer (score 5):

Since it only has 24 lines, we can use brute force to list all the possible intersections.

```
 test[{{pp1_, pp2_}, {pp3_, pp4_}}] := 
 Module[{a, b, x1, y1, x2, y2, sol},
  {x1, y1} = pp1 + a (pp2 - pp1); {x2, y2} = pp3 + b (pp4 - pp3);
  sol = Solve[{x1 == x2, y1 == y2, 0 <= a <= 1, 0 <= b <= 1}, {a, b}];
  If[sol != {}, pp1 + a (pp2 - pp1) /. sol, {}]
 ]
points = test /@ Tuples[{Partition[p1, 2], Partition[p2, 2]}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
pic = ListLinePlot[Join[Partition[p1, 2], Partition[p2, 2]], 
  Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> Black, ImageSize -> {500, 300}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[points]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is not as neat as eldo but post as another (rather hamfisted) approach:

```
lin[p_, q_] := p + (q - p) s
linv[p_, q_, v_] := p + (q - p) v
eqn[list_, v_] := linv[##, v] & @@@ Partition[list, 2]
```

Visualizing:

```
all = Show[ParametricPlot[lin @@@ Partition[p2, 2], {s, 0, 1}], 
  ParametricPlot[lin @@@ Partition[p1, 2], {s, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Finding points of intersection:

```
soln = {#1, Solve[#1 == #2, {s, t}]} & @@@ 
   Tuples[{eqn[p1, s], eqn[p2, t]}];
pts = #1 /. #2[[1]] & @@@ 
   Select[soln, 
    And[0 < #[[2, 1, 1, 2]] < 1, 0 < #[[2, 1, 2, 2]] < 1] &];
```

The points:

```
{{357.665, 43.8996}, {386.456, 171.367}, {174.78, 217.866}, {67.659, 
  224.232}, {377.821, 391.4}, {309.378, 409.539}, {203.788, 
  395.3}, {392.522, 538.096}, {244.015, 538.739}, {110.507, 
  513.497}, {345.2, 761.563}, {113.367, 715.586}}
```

Visualizing:

```
int = Show[all, Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for any lines, including vertical lines, but does not check for the cases where there are no or infinitely many intersections:

```
LineIntersectionPoint[{p1_, p2_}, {q1_, q2_}] := {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
  First@Solve[
    Cross[p2 - p1].({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} - p1) == 
     Cross[q2 - q1].({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} - q1) == 0, {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}]
```

or equivalently:

```
LineIntersectionPoint[{p1_, p2_}, {q1_, q2_}] := {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} /. 
  First@FindInstance[
    Cross[p2 - p1].({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} - p1) == 
     Cross[q2 - q1].({\[FormalX], \[FormalY]} - q1) == 0, {\[FormalX], \[FormalY]}]
```