# Find intersection points with V10

Tags: graphics, algorithm, version-10

My question departs from this one: [Find intersection of pairs of straight lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51391/find-intersection-of-pairs-of-straight-lines/51399#51399)

but now I want to find the points with the new V10 `Region`-functions.

```
lines =
 {{Line[{{243.8`, 77.`}, {467.4`, 12.`}}], Line[{{356.8`, 32.`}, {363.2`, 120.`}}]},
  {Line[{{291.8`, 130.`}, {476.`, 210.5`}}], Line[{{346.`, 245.`}, {393.8`, 158.`}}]},
  {Line[{{103.2`, 327.`}, {245.2`, 110.5`}}], Line[{{163.8`, 211.5`}, {230.2`, 250.`}}]},
  {Line[{{47.4`, 343.`}, {87.4`, 108.5`}}], Line[{{54.6`, 225.`}, {139.6`, 220.`}}]},
  {Line[{{371.`, 506.5`}, {384.6`, 277.`}}], Line[{{366.`, 394.5`}, {451.8`, 372.`}}]},
  {Line[{{264.6`, 525.5`}, {353.8`, 294.5`}}], Line[{{241.`, 398.`}, {321.`, 411.5`}}]},
  {Line[{{113.2`, 484.5`}, {296.`, 304.5`}}], Line[{{163.2`, 347.`}, {213.2`, 406.5`}}]},
  {Line[{{459.6`, 604.5`}, {320.2`, 466.5`}}], Line[{{332.4`, 596.5`}, {402.4`, 528.5`}}]},
  {Line[{{288.2`, 630.5`}, {199.6`, 446.5`}}], Line[{{176.`, 585.5`}, {256.`, 530.5`}}]},
  {Line[{{138.8`, 615.5`}, {81.8`, 410.`}}], Line[{{38.2`, 553.`}, {122.4`, 507.`}}]},
  {Line[{{232.4`, 795.`}, {461.8`, 727.`}}], Line[{{345.2`, 774.5`}, {345.2`, 688.`}}]},
  {Line[{{27.4`, 671.5`}, {206.8`, 763.5`}}], Line[{{104.6`, 728.`}, {161.8`, 647.`}}]}};
```

This function finds the points but is horribly slow:

```
(points = Point /@ RegionCentroid /@ DiscretizeRegion /@ RegionUnion @@@ lines); //
   Timing // First
```

> 1.591210

```
Graphics[{lines, {Red, PointSize@0.02, points}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The next function finds the same points in less time (0.28 seconds), but is ugly and probably not general enough.

```
points = Cases[Show[DiscretizeRegion /@ RegionIntersection @@@ lines],
   {a_Real, b_Real} :> Point[{a, b}], Infinity];
```

I hope somebody can suggest a fast and terse V10-method to find intersection points in 2 dimensions

Comment: Is something like `Point[{x, y}] /. Solve[{x, y} \[Element] #, {x, y}] & /@ RegionIntersection @@@ lines` the sort of thing you want?  You have lots of requirements, *fast*, *terse*, *V10*, which might not be satisfied simultaneously.  But this one is about four times faster than your last one.

Comment: @Michael E2 Yes, that's what I was hoping for. Why don't you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know all pairs of line segments intersect, then the following is about four times faster than using `DiscretizeRegion`:

```
points = (Point[{x, y}] /. Solve[{x, y} ∈ #, {x, y}] & /@ RegionIntersection @@@ lines); //
  AbsoluteTiming // First
Graphics[{lines, {Red, PointSize@0.02, points}}, Frame -> True]
(*
  0.040551
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Bug?**

[Tested on beta V10 -- my institution is a little slow updating its software distribution.]

I feel this should work, but `Solve` emits error messages when `RegionIntersection` is used will `Apply`.  `Solve` works perfectly on an explicit individual region intersection.

```
SeedRandom[1];
lines2 = Map[Line, RandomReal[{500, 800}, {5, 2, 2, 2}], {2}];
points = Point[p] /. Flatten[Solve[p ∈ #, p] & /@ RegionIntersection @@@ Join[lines2, lines], 1];
Graphics[{lines, 
  MapIndexed[{Hue[i/First[#2]], #1} &, lines2], {Red, PointSize@0.02, points}},
  Frame -> True]
```

> Solve::elemc: Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition `p ∈ RegionIntersection[Line[{{618.802,710.142},{563.548,724.597}}],Line[{{626.855,574.248},{<<17>>,<<18>>}}]]`. >>
>
> ...rest omitted...

The first message corresponds to the second pair:

```
lines2[[2]]
(*
  {Line[{{618.802, 710.142}, {563.548, 724.597}}], 
   Line[{{626.855, 574.248}, {793.152, 747.549}}]}
*)
```

This gives the same error message:

```
Solve[p ∈ RegionIntersection @@ lines2[[2]], p]
```

However, explicit code works fine:

```
Solve[p ∈ 
  RegionIntersection[
   Line[{{618.8018244645762`, 710.1421345826734`},
         {563.5477937162382`, 724.5970644448844`}}],
    Line[{{626.8551948019847`, 574.2484342592024`},
         {793.151528522233`, 747.5488818465542`}}]],
  p]
(*
  {}
*)
```

A workaround is to use `DeleteCases` (and `Quiet` if desired):

```
points = Point[p] /. 
   Flatten[DeleteCases[
     Solve[p ∈ #, p] & /@ 
      RegionIntersection @@@ Join[lines2, lines], _Solve], 1];
Graphics[{lines, 
  MapIndexed[{Hue[First[#2]/5], #1} &, lines2], {Red, PointSize@0.02, 
   points}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: am too slow...mine essentially a variant of yours...+1

Comment: I'd be will to post the second part as a separate is-this-a-bug question, if someone can confirm it seems like misbehavior and that it can be reproduced.

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks!  I thought I was slow because the second part was annoying me no end.

Comment: very interesting update...will test my approach when get chance...with this full set of lines wrote my code to remove line segments which do not intersect but have not tested larger set...off to bed now...perhaps tomorrow

Answer (score 9):

With *Mathematica 10* you can use:

```
ps[{l1_, l2_}] := Solve[p ∈ l1 ∧ p ∈ l2, p]
```

and then

```
points2 = Point[p] /. Map[ps[#] &, lines] // Flatten
```

For a large number of lines `ParallelMap` should give an additional speedup.

Comment: You might want to use _?NumericQ for exact solutions (in case any exact input is present).

Comment: @Karsten Thanks for your answer. Even with these few lines `ParallelMap` more than doubles speed (0.038 seconds)

Answer (score 5):

```
ints[l1_, l2_] := Module[{rg, x, y, res},
   rg = RegionIntersection[l1, l2]; 
   res = {x, y} /. ToRules[Reduce[RegionMember[rg, {x, y}]]];
   If[And @@ (NumericQ /@ res), res = res, res = Sequence[]]; res];
pair[dat_] := Subsets[dat, {2}]
```

As the lines have already been paired:

```
li01 = Graphics[{{Hue[RandomReal[]], Thick, #} & /@ lines, {Red, 
    PointSize[0.03], Point[ints @@@ lines]}}]
```

[image]

Or pretending you just had a bunch of lines:

```
li02 = Graphics[{{Thick, Blue, lines}, {Red, PointSize[0.04], 
    Point[ints @@@ pair[Flatten@lines]]}}]
```

[image]