# cross point of intersecting lines

Tags: equation-solving

What is the easiest way to find the crossing point of two intersecting lines passing lets say through points line1 = {p1,p2}, line2 = {p3,p4}?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: `findInter[{p1_, p2_}, {p3_, p4_}] :=   t p1 + (1 - t) p2 /.    Solve[t p1 + (1 - t) p2 == t1 p3 + (1 - t1) p4, {t, t1}][[1]]; findInter[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}]`

Comment: `f[t_, l_] := First@l - Subtract @@ l t; 
findInter[l1_, l2_] := 
 f[t, l1] /. 
  Solve[f[t, l1] == f[t1, l2]]; findInter[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}}, {{0, 
   1}, {1, 2}}]`

Comment: Duplicate: "[Find intersection of pairs of straight lines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51391/280)."

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
line1 = {p1, p2}; line2 = {p3, p4};
```

you could define two points on these lines:

```
l1 = {1 - u1, u1}.line1;
l2 = {1 - u2, u2}.line2;
```

and just solve for the intersection:

```
l1 /. Solve[l1 == l2, {u1, u2}]
```

---

Alternatively (and more elegantly) you could use projective geometry, where `Cross[p1,p2]` is the line between two points p1 and p2 and `Cross[l1,l2]` is the intersection between two lines l1 and l2:

```
euclidean2homogenous = Append[#, 1] &;
homogenous2euclidean = #[[;; -2]]/#[[-1]] &;

line1 = Cross[euclidean2homogenous@p1, euclidean2homogenous@p2];
line2 = Cross[euclidean2homogenous@p3, euclidean2homogenous@p4];

intersection = Cross[line1, line2]

homogenous2euclidean[intersection]
```

Comment: Dear niki thank you very much. Great help for a newbie.