# Finding intersection of two infinitely long lines using points

Tags: plotting, graphics, computational-geometry, geometry, intersection

**EDITED**

In the [Find intersection of pairs of straight lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51391/find-intersection-of-pairs-of-straight-lines) problem, it is assumed that line are intersected by default and the purpose is to find the intersection points. In the present problem, two lines are completely separated as bellows:

[image]

The coordinates of the lines are :

```
Line1={{0,0},{1,1}};
Line2={{7,0},{5,3}};
```

How is it possible to calculate the coordinates of **the intersection point** of these two lines and plot it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know the math involved?

Comment: I see a challenge here to provide a formulation in Mathematica in vector symbols only, i.e. no components should appear. Still busy trying to find it ...

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang, the answer I posted in the linked dupe does precisely that.