# intersection between polygon. Algorithm to check it

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, polygons

I'm working on an algorithm which should check if two polygons, described by their vertex coordinates, are: one inside the other, are intersecting or are separated

image below describe this three cases:
[image: example]

i'm thinking about how to do it but i'm not having any idea.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right place to ask such a question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
R1 = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 0}}];
R2 = Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1/3, 1/2}, {0, 1/2}}];

Graphics[{R1, Red, R2}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
Catenate @ Map[RegionMember[R1, #] &, List @@ R2] // MemberQ[#, True] &
```

> False

```
R3 = Polygon[{{0, 1}, {3/4, 1/2}, {0, 1/2}}];

Graphics[{R1, Red, R3}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
Catenate @ Map[RegionMember[R1, #] &, List @@ R3] // MemberQ[#, True] &
```

> True

"Inside the other"

```
Catenate @ Map[RegionMember[R1, #] &, List @@ R1] // FreeQ[#, False] &
```

> True

Comment: many thanks, should help

Comment: This is no general solution, your code fails for all cases where the first polygon doesn't have any of it's veritces inside the second polygon. Swapping `R1` and `R3` results in a wrong answer. Some cases can't be solved e.g. `R1 = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 3}, {1, 0}}; R2 = {{-1, -0.5}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}};`

Answer (score 6):

Using `RegionIntersection` and `Area`:

```
PolygonIntersectingQ[poly1_, poly2_] := Module[{m1, m2, area},
   {m1, m2} = MeshRegion[#, Polygon[Range@Length@#]] & /@ {poly1, poly2};
   area = Area@RegionIntersection[m1, m2];
   Switch[area,
    0, False,
    Area@m1, poly1,
    Area@m2, poly2,
    _, True]];

poly1 = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 3}, {1, 0}};
poly2 = {{-1, -0.5}, {2, 3}, {4, 2}};
PolygonIntersectingQ[poly1, poly2]
```

> True

The function returns `True` if the polygons are intersecting, `False` if they are not intersecting and the inner polygon if one polygon is enclosed in the other.

Comment: How would you handle the "inside the other"-case?

Comment: @eldo should be good now.

Answer (score 3):

using this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51425/2079

```
segsegintersectionQ[lines_] := Module[{
   md = Subtract @@ (Plus @@ # & /@ lines), 
   sub = Subtract @@ # & /@ lines, det}, det = -Det[sub];
  TrueQ[And @@ (Abs[#] <= 1 & /@ #)] &@(Det[{#[[1]], md}]/
       det & /@ ({#, Reverse@#} &@sub))];
```

and this:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9408/2079

```
testpoint[poly_, pt_] := 
 Round[(Total@
       Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 
        2 Pi, -Pi]/2/Pi)] != 0

Which[  Or @@ Flatten@Outer[segsegintersectionQ[{##}] & ,
 Partition[Append[poly1, First@poly1], 2, 1],
 Partition[Append[poly2, First@poly2], 2, 1], 1] ,
                                True ,
  testpoint[poly1, poly2[[1]]], True,
  testpoint[poly2, poly1[[1]]], True]
```

I haven't tested but I suspect this will be faster than the `Region` approaches.

(You could use `Or` instead of `Which` if you don't need to separately treat the inside cases.)