# Polygon with an extended Boundary

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have a (not necessarily convex) `Polygon`, and want to create another `Region` that can be seen as an extended boundary of the first polygon.

It should be quite simple; I tried it by creating a second polygon with 10% larger size, that I shift. It works for simple shapes such as squares, but it doesn't produce a boundary for different shapes.

```
myCoordinates = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
mypolygon = Polygon[myCoordinates];
dilatation = 1.1;
maxX = Max[myCoordinates[[;; , 1]]];
maxY = Max[myCoordinates[[;; , 2]]];
myCoordinatesLarge = dilatation*myCoordinates;
myCoordinatesLarge[[;; , 1]] -= (dilatation - 1)*maxX/2;
myCoordinatesLarge[[;; , 2]] -= (dilatation - 1)*maxY/2;
mypolygon2 = Polygon[myCoordinatesLarge];

RR = RegionIntersection[mypolygon2, mypolygon]
Show[Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Gray], mypolygon, mypolygon2}], HighlightMesh[DiscretizeRegion[RR], 2]]
```

[image: dilated square]

However, if my coordinates are

```
myCoordinates = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {3, 0}};
```

then I get this area without a boundary at the hypotenuse

[image: triangle]

The best would be to start from `RegionCentroid[mypolygon]` and inflate the polygon without changing its `RegionCentroid`, but I don't know how to do this.

**Update:**
The method in the answers works for simple shapes such as squares or triangles, but if I have slightly more complex shapes, the result has no real boundary

```
myCoordinates = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}};
mypolygon = Polygon[myCoordinates];
mypolygon2 = TransformedRegion[mypolygon, ScalingTransform[{2, 2}, RegionCentroid[mypolygon]]];
RR = RegionIntersection[mypolygon2, mypolygon];
Show[Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Gray], mypolygon, mypolygon2}], HighlightMesh[DiscretizeRegion[RR], 2]]
```

[image: concave example]

Comment: `mypolygon2 = Scale[ mypolygon, 1.5, RegionCentroid[ mypolygon ] ]`

Comment: Wow that is the direct way how I expected it. However unfortunatly the boundary on the left is larger than on the bottom and at the hypothenuse. Do you know how to make the boundary equal at all sides? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a function that inflates a polygon.  It creates a new polygon whose sides are parallel to the original, but displaced by a specified difference.  Actually, it takes the coordinates of polygon vertices, not a `Polygon` object.  Here's the function definition:

```
Clear[inflate]
inflate[gap_, pts_] := With[{
   c = Join[pts[[-1 ;;]], pts, pts[[;; 1]]]},
  Table[Block[{dir1, dir2, dist1, dist2,
     p1, p2, p3, perp1, perp2, q1, q2, q3, q4, x, y},
    {p1, p2, p3} = {c[[n - 1]], c[[n]], c[[n + 1]]};
    {dist1, dist2} = Norm /@ {p2 - p1, p3 - p2};
    {dir1, dir2} = {p2 - p1, p3 - p2}/{dist1, dist2};
    {perp1, perp2} = {{-Last[dir1], First[dir1]}, 
       {-Last[dir2], First[dir2]}};
    {q1, q2} = With[{delta = gap*perp1}, {p1 + delta, p2 + delta}];
    {q3, q4} = With[{delta = gap*perp2}, {p2 + delta, p3 + delta}];
    eqn1 = With[{delta = q2 - q1, pt = {x, y} - q1},
      First[delta] Last[pt] == Last[delta] First[pt]];
    eqn2 = With[{delta = q4 - q3, pt = {x, y} - q3},
      First[delta] Last[pt] == Last[delta] First[pt]];
    {x, y} /. First@Solve[{eqn1, eqn2}, {x, y}]],
   {n, 2, Length[pts] + 1}]]
```

Here is an example of how it can be used with one of your coordinate lists.

```
coords = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}};
poly1 = Polygon[coords];
Manipulate[
 poly2 = Polygon[offset[gap, coords]];
 Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[1/3], Blue, poly1,
    EdgeForm[Black], LightBlue, poly2}],
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-1, 2}}, Axes -> True],
 {{gap, 1/4}, 0, 1/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: example]

**How does it work?**
Take three consecutive vertices, $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$. The line $p_1p_2$ gets moved perpendicular to itself, and $p_2p_3$ moves perpendicular to itself. The intersection of the new lines is a vertex of the inflated polygon.

So, calculate the direction (cosines) from $p_1$ to $p_2$, then find the perpendicular direction.  Translate $p_1$ and $p_2$ by the gap distance to points $q_1$ and $q_2$.  Likewise, translate $p_2$ and $p_3$ perpendicular to $p_2p_3$ to get points $q_3$ and $q_4$.  Use the two-point form to get equations for lines $q_1q_2$ and $q_3q_4$.  Solve the equations for the intersection.

Use `Table` to loop over the list of coordinates.  To make the iteration easier, use `With` to extend the coordinate list forward and backwards. This implementation is pretty inefficient: each direction, displacement, equation, etc., is calculated twice.

The same function will deflate a polygon if the gap is negative, or if the coordinate list is reversed.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[polygonInflate]
polygonInflate[δ_][coords_] := Module[{inflines = InfiniteLine /@ 
     Partition[coords, 2, 1, {1, 1}], 
   trs = TranslationTransform /@ (δ (Cross /@ 
     Normalize /@ Differences[Append[coords, First@coords]]))},
  RegionIntersection @@@ 
     Partition[MapThread[TransformedRegion, {inflines, trs}], 2, 1, {1, 1}] /. 
       Point[x_] :> x]
```

***Examples:***

```
myCoordinates1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {3, 0}};

Graphics[{ Opacity[.5], Red, Polygon@myCoordinates1, Blue, 
  Polygon @ polygonInflate[-.1] @ myCoordinates1}, 
 PlotRange -> RegionBounds[Polygon@myCoordinates1], 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
myCoordinates2 = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {0.5, 0.5}};

Graphics[{ Opacity[.5], Red, Polygon@myCoordinates2, Blue, 
  Polygon @ polygonInflate[-.1] @ myCoordinates2}, 
 PlotRange -> RegionBounds[Polygon@myCoordinates2], 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[77]
myCoordinates3 = Reverse@#[[Most@Last@FindShortestTour[#]]] &@RandomReal[5, {12, 2}];

Graphics[{ Opacity[.5], Red, Polygon @ myCoordinates3, Blue, 
  Polygon @ polygonInflate[-.2] @ myCoordinates3}, 
 PlotRange -> RegionBounds[Polygon @ myCoordinates3], 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Show[Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Red, Polygon @ myCoordinates3}], 
 DiscretizeRegion[Polygon @ polygonInflate[-.2] @ myCoordinates3]], 
 PlotRange -> RegionBounds[Polygon @ myCoordinates3], 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

***Update:*** Slightly streamlined implementation of @LouisB's cool idea:

```
Clear[findCoordsF, inflateF]
findCoordsF[gap_] := Module[{perps, eqns, x, y, difs = Differences[#], 
     disps = #[[;; 2]] + gap (Cross /@ Normalize /@ Differences[#])},
    perps = {x, y} - # & /@ disps;
    eqns = difs[[#, 1]] perps[[#, 2]] == difs[[#, 2]] perps[[#, 1]] & /@ {1, 2};
    {x, y} /. First@Solve[eqns, {x, y}]] &;

inflateF[gap_][pts_] := findCoordsF[gap] /@ Partition[pts, 3, 1, {2, 2}]

coords = myCoordinates2;
Manipulate[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[1/3], Blue, Polygon[c], 
    EdgeForm[Black], LightBlue, Polygon[inflateF[gap][c]]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False], 
 {{gap, .1}, -1/2, 1/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, coords}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) with a [`ScalingTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingTransform). Your polygon:

```
p = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {3, 0}}];
```

Using [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion):

```
extended = TransformedRegion[
    p,
    ScalingTransform[{1.1, 1.1}, RegionCentroid[p]]
]
```

> `Polygon[{{-0.10000000000000009, -0.03333333333333338}, 
>   {-0.10000000000000009, 1.0666666666666667}, {3.2, 
>   -0.03333333333333338}}, {1, 3, 2}]`

Check:

```
Graphics[{Red, extended, Blue, p}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is really cool. I did the same, but with a really ugly for-loop. What is strange in this solution is that the boundary on the left is larger than the bournary on the bottom and the hypothenus. Do you have an idea how to fix this too, and make the boundary same size at each edge? Thanks so much!

Comment: I updated the example accordingly, with a more complex polygon. Do you know how to adapt your solution to create a boundary there, too? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as Louis's idea, but I was able to devise a much shorter implementation, which **does not rely on `Solve[]`**:

```
(* intersection of two lines; cf. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85903 *)
lis[{{p1_, d1_}, {p2_, d2_}}] := With[{sol = LeastSquares[Transpose[{d1, d2}], p2 - p1]}, 
    Mean[{p1 + sol[[1]] d1, p2 - sol[[2]] d2}]]

(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22587 *)
PolygonSignedArea[pts_?MatrixQ] := Total[Det /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1]]/2

PolygonInflate[Polygon[p1_?MatrixQ], h_?NumericQ] := Module[{sides, sig},
       sig = Sign[PolygonSignedArea[p1]];
       sides = With[{d = Normalize[Subtract @@ #]}, {Mean[#] + h sig Cross[d], d}] & /@
               Partition[p1, 2, 1, 1];
       Polygon[RotateRight[lis /@ Partition[sides, 2, 1, 1]]]]
```

As a demonstration:

```
p1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}};

Manipulate[Graphics[{{Red, PolygonInflate[Polygon[p1], h]},
                     {Opacity[1/2, Blue], Polygon[p1]}},
                    PlotRange -> {{-1, 3}, {-1, 3}}],
           {{h, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Manipulate object]

A more difficult example:

```
poly = Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonData["Test01", "Polygon"];

Graphics[{{Red, PolygonInflate[poly, 1/5]}, {Blue, poly},
          {Yellow, PolygonInflate[poly, -1/5]}}]
```

[image: a difficult polygon]