# Enlarge polygon by fixed edge distance

Tags: regions, geometry, polygons, rescale

I wish to create a larger polygon from a smaller one through orthogonally translating each edge by a fixed distance. [`RegionResize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionResize.html) with a bounding box given by [`RegionBounds`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBounds.html) works when my polygon *is* a box:

```
p1 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}];

dist = .3;
b = {#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] + dist} & /@ RegionBounds[p1];

p2 = RegionResize[p1, b];
```

Below, the red square is `p1` and the dashed edges border `p2` composed of edges each a distance `dist` from their corresponding ones in `p1`.

[image]

But when my input polygon is not a box, this method does not work:

```
p1 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, .7}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}];
b = {#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] + dist} & /@ RegionBounds[p1];
p2 = RegionResize[p1, b];
```

[image]

Notice the top edges of `p1` and `p2` are *closer* than `dist` from one-another.

My polygons are in general quite complicated. Naturally I can compute the corner coordinates of the expanded polygon myself geometrically but it is irksome to do so when existing functions do so *close* to what I need.

In words, I wish to obtain a polygon as described by this process:

- translate each edge in `p2` a distance `dist` along an orthogonal line, *away* from the polygon area.
- extend each edge until it intersects with its neighbouring edges.
- return the polygon whose vertices are the ordered list of these coordinates of intersection.

Is there an elegant paradigmatic way to do this in Mathematica, e.g. using the [derived regions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedRegions.html) functions?

Comment: This question / answer may be useful  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211888/22158

Comment: @LouisB indeed my question is a duplicate and you've already solved it, thanks!

Comment: @bbgodfrey that's the question LouisB linked in the comment above, and that cited in the close vote I started (to mark this question as duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Would it be sufficient to scale it from the centroid?

```
factor = 1.1;
center = RegionCentroid[p1];
ScalingTransform[{factor, factor}, c][p1]
```

There is also RegionDilation:

```
RegionDilation[p1, (ScalingTransform[{.1, .1}] @* TranslationTransform[-c])[p1]]
```

I chose the .1 scale (i.e. the amount of dilation) arbitrarily.

**Update**

I thought I should explain and provide a caveat. RegionDilation is basically doing a Minkowski sum. If you do this with a disk, you get a uniform "border" added to your region. The problem with that is that you won't have the sharp corners that you wanted. So, I just used a region that was the same shape as your original. My thinking was that similarity would give us back those corners. But on second thought, I don't think it gives us that uniform border. You might be stuck doing the algebra.

Or maybe you can translate each edge by the desired amount, use them to create infinite lines (InfiniteLine) that you can then intersect pairwise. That'll give you the new corners.

Comment: It's not sufficient to *scale* since I do not *a priori* know the scale factor nor the length (in whatever measure) of the original polygon. How would you determine `factor` from `dist`?

Comment: Well, the infinte line solution is the better way to go anyway, but since you asked, you have all of the vertices, and therefore sides, and so determining a scale from the offset would not be difficult.