# Checking if two line segments intersect

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, geometry

What is the fastest way of checking whether two line segments of the form `Line[{p1,p2}]` intersect at a point? I don't need to know what the point of intersection is, but only if they do intersect.

My initial approach was to simply use `RegionIntersection` and write something like

```
LineIntersectionQ[l1_, l2_] := RegionDimension@RegionIntersection[l1, l2] == 0
```

But this seems to be slow. Any ideas?

Comment: Related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51391/58370

Comment: Just to get definitions clear here: Do you mean to use this for `Line` objects in the plane (2D) only, or also in 3D or even nD?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I asked for general dimensions, but I'd be happy with a more efficient solution for either the 2D or 3D cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try this:

```
Clear[interQ];
interQ[ Line[{v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ}], 
        Line[{v3_?VectorQ, v4_?VectorQ}]] := Block[{
    m = Transpose[ {v1 - v2, v4 - v3}], vL},
   
   If[ Det[m] == 0, False, 
      vL = LeastSquares[ m , v4 - v2];
      (* Sow[ v1*vL[[1]] + v2*(1-vL[[1]])];  *)
      0 <= vL[[1]] <= 1 && 0 <= vL[[2]] <= 1]];
```

Edit 2022-6-10:  Adding cases for higher dimensional spaces as requested.

(* Assuming v1,v2,v3, and v4 have rational or integer coordinates *)

```
interExactQ[ 
  Line[{v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ}], 
  Line[{v3_?VectorQ, v4_?VectorQ}] ] := Block[{
   m = Transpose[{v2 - v1, v3 - v4}], vL}, 
  vL = LeastSquares[ m, v3 - v1];
  (* 
  Print["Dist Between Lines = ",  Norm[ m . vL - (v3-v1)]];
  Print["Numerical Lambdas = ", N[vL]]; *)
  
  Norm[ m . vL - (v3 - v1)] == 0 &&
   0 <= vL[[1]] <= 1 && 
   0 <= vL[[2]] <= 1 ];
```

(* For double precision floating point numbers there are numerical issues, the code below seems to work.  If the coordinates have iD digits of precision, replace 10^14 with 10^(iD-2) *)

```
interDoubleRealQ[ 
  Line[{v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ}], 
  Line[{v3_?VectorQ, v4_?VectorQ}] ] := Block[{
   m = Transpose[{v2 - v1, v3 - v4}], vL}, 
  vL = LeastSquares[ m, v3 - v1];
  (* 
  Print["Dist Between Lines = ",  Norm[ m . vL - (v3 - v1)]];
  Print["Numerical Lambdas = ", N[vL]]; *)
  vEig = Sort[ Eigenvalues[ Transpose[ m ] . m]];
  Norm[ m . vL - (v3 - v1)] <= 
    Norm[ {v1, v2, v3, v4}]*vEig[[2]]/vEig[[1]]/10^14 &&
   0 <= vL[[1]] <= 1 && 0 <= vL[[2]] <= 1 ]
```

Comment: If you're absolutely concerned about numerical stability, then `Sort[Eigenvalues[Transpose[ m ] . m]]` is totally the wrong way to do it (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359397)). Instead, do `vEig = SingularValueList[m]` and then you can use the check `Norm[m . vL - (v3 - v1)] <= Norm[{v1, v2, v3, v4}]*(vEig[[1]]/vEig[[2]])^2/1*^14` (tho you might want to go for an adjustable tolerance instead).

Comment: @J.M.     Cool!   Let me think about this!   :)

Answer (score 14):

In 2D (and only there), you can use the undocumented function `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` to find the point of intersection. This is often an order of magnitude faster than `RegionIntersection`. If there isn't any intersection point, then an empty list is returned.

```
plot[l1_, l2_] := Graphics[{Thick, PointSize[0.025], Darker@Green, Point @@ l1, l1, Darker@Red, l2, Point @@ l2}];

l1 = Line@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
l2 = Line@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}];
pt = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{l1, l2}];
Graphics[{l1, l2, Red, Point[pt]}]
```

So something like

```
LineIntersectionQ2[l1_, l2_] := Length[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{l1, l2}]] > 0
```

could be quite a lot faster on average.

Apparently, this finds only intersection points if they are isolated. The following examples shall illustrate this:

```
plot[l1_, l2_] := Graphics[{Thick, PointSize[0.025],
    Darker@Green, Point @@ l1, l1,
    Darker@Blue, l2, Point @@ l2,
    Red, Point[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{l1, l2}]]
    },
   Frame -> True];

l1 = Line[{{-1., 0}, {1., 0.}}];
l2 = Line[{{0., 1.}, {0., -1}}];
plot[l1, l2]

l1 = Line[{{-1., 0}, {1., 0.}}];
l2 = Line[{{1., 2.}, {1., 0.}}];
plot[l1, l2]

l1 = Line[{{-1., 0}, {1., 0.}}];
l2 = Line[{{0., 2.}, {0., 0.}}];
plot[l1, l2]

l1 = Line[{{0., 0.}, {2., 0.}}];
l2 = Line[{{1., 0.}, {3., 0.}}];
plot[l1, l2]

l1 = Line[{{0., 0.}, {2., 0.}}];
l2 = Line[{{2., 0.}, {4., 0.}}];
plot[l1, l2]

l1 = Line[{{0., 0.}, {2., 0.}}];
l2 = Line[{{3., 0.}, {5., 0.}}];
plot[l1, l2]

l1 = Line[{{0., 1.}, {2., 1.}}];
l2 = Line[{{1., 0.}, {3., 0.}}];
plot[l1, l2]
```

I am not sure whether this is what you are looking for. You say that you want to know when the line segments `intersect at a point`. Do you happen to mean `intersect at a single point`? In that case `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` seems to be your friend.

Anyways, `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` is still super slow. It can only test a few thousand line pairs per second. I recently wrote an C++ implementation of the [Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm). That one can test up to 20 million line segment pairs per second. Just to give you an idea how far one can push this.

Comment: Would you please elaborate upon the non-intersecting parallel cases where the two line segments could be in a horizontal line, a vertical line, or at a slope. Also the intersecting parallel case, where one line segment is a 'subset' of a larger line segment. i.e. partially or fully intersecting case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added a couple of examples in my answer. Feel free to test a couple of further configurations of your interest. The slopes of the lines themselfes should not matter. (Developers at Wolfram are not dumb.)

Comment: My own solution doesn't work satisfactorily if there are parallel lines intersecting at multiple intersecting points, so I wanted to ask you if a better/alternate solution existed for such cases. You seem like the experienced person to whose authority I could defer to. I never implied that the developers were dumb.

Comment: "I never implied that the developers were dumb." Sure. And I never implied that you meant to imply that! ;)

Comment: Btw., neither did I mean to imply that you were dumb. =)

Comment: We may be dumb but we're not deaf....

Answer (score 11):

```
t := RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2]
```

ln1 and ln2 will be the coordinates for a `Line` or `InfiniteLine` as needed later.

```
ln1 = {t, t};
ln2 = {t, t};

Clear[sol, x, y]
sol = Solve[{x, y} \[Element] 
    InfiniteLine@ln1 \[And] {x, y} \[Element] InfiniteLine@ln2, {x, 
   y}]

{x, y} = {x, y} /. sol[[1]]
```

Let's say this gives us the following pt of intersection for infinite lines through ln1 and ln2.

> {5.77478, -1.71834}

The point of intersection has to be on both line segments.

```
{x, y} \[Element] Line@ln1
```

> False

```
{x, y} \[Element] Line@ln2
```

> True

```
Graphics[{Red, Line[ln1], Red, Line[ln2], Black, Point@Midpoint@ln1, 
  Point@Midpoint@ln2, Blue, PointSize[0.05], Point[{x, y}]
  }]
```

Visualization for this this particular non-intersecting case is as follows (The smaller dots are just the midpoints of the line segments):

[image]

Visualization for an intersecting case:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

How about negating the output of [`RegionDisjoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint.html)?

Borrowing a specific example from the [ref page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint.html#1836122447):

```
SeedRandom[1];
l1 = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}];
l2 = Line[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]];

!RegionDisjoint[l1, l2] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.002878, False}
> ```

Answer (score 10):

This answer provides results of timing tests of the other answers, at least the ones that provided compatible MMA code.  The test methods are shown below.  With a smaller number indicating a faster method of determining whether the line segments intersect, here is a summary of the latest results:  $$\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Original} & 11.5 \\
 \text{Henrik} & 3.019 \\
 \text{Greg} & 5.3 \\
 \text{Syed} & 9.990 \\
 \text{irchans} & 0.16 \\
 \text{Eric} & 6.99 \\
 \text{Lukasz} & 0.12 \\
\end{array}$$

#### Test Procedure

First, generate a test set of line pairs from a pool of candidate lines.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[123]

nlines = 90;
pool = Line /@ RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {nlines, 2, 2}];
set1 = Subsets[pool, {2}];
tmax = 10  (* time in seconds for repeated timings *);

$Version  (*12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)*)
Graphics[pool, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Small, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

#### Test functions

```
(*  Original function *)
ClearAll[LineIntersectionQ]
LineIntersectionQ[l1_, l2_] := 
 RegionDimension@RegionIntersection[l1, l2] == 0

n0 = "Original";
{t0, r0} = RepeatedTiming[LineIntersectionQ @@@ set1, tmax];

(* Henrik Schumacher's answer *)
ClearAll[hsFunc]
hsFunc[l1_, l2_] := 
 Length[Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{l1, l2}]] > 0

n1 = "Henrik";
{t1, r1} = RepeatedTiming[hsFunc @@@ set1, tmax];

(* Greg Hurst's answer *)
ClearAll[ghFunc]
ghFunc[l1_, l2_] := Not@RegionDisjoint[l1, l2]

n2 = "Greg";
{t2, r2} = RepeatedTiming[ghFunc @@@ set1, tmax];

(* Syed's answer *)
ClearAll[x, y, sFunc]
sFunc[ln1_, 
  ln2_] := ({x, y} \[Element] ln1 \[And] {x, y} \[Element] ln2) /. 
  First@
   Solve[{x, y} \[Element] 
      InfiniteLine @@ ln1 \[And] {x, y} \[Element] 
      InfiniteLine @@ ln2, {x, y}]

n3 = "Syed";
{t3, r3} = RepeatedTiming[sFunc @@@ set1, tmax];

(*  irchans' answer  *)
ClearAll[interQ];
interQ[Line[{v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ}], 
  Line[{v3_?VectorQ, v4_?VectorQ}]] := 
 Block[{m = Transpose[{v1 - v2, v4 - v3}], vL}, 
  If[Det[m] == 0, False, vL = LeastSquares[m, v4 - v2];
   0 <= vL[[1]] <= 1 && 0 <= vL[[2]] <= 1]]

n4 = "irchans";
{t4, r4} = RepeatedTiming[interQ @@@ set1, tmax];

(*  Eric Tower's answer  *)
ClearAll[intersect]
intersect[Line[{a_, b_}], Line[{c_, d_}]] := 
 Module[{cap}, 
  cap = Solve[{a t + b (1 - t) == c s + d (1 - s), 0 <= t <= 1, 
     0 <= s <= 1}, {s, t}, Reals];
  And[Length[cap] == 1, NumberQ[s /. cap[[1]]], NumberQ[t /. cap[[1]]]]]

n5 = "Eric";
{t5, r5} = RepeatedTiming[intersect @@@ set1, tmax] // Quiet;

(* Lukasz's answer *)
ClearAll[interQ6]
interQ6[Line@{u1_?VectorQ, u2_?VectorQ},
  Line@{v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ}] := Block[{},
  And[Det[{u2 - u1, v1 - u2}] Det[{u2 - u1, v2 - u2}] < 0, 
   Det[{v2 - v1, u1 - v2}] Det[{v2 - v1, u2 - v2}] < 0]]

n6 = "Lukasz";
{t6, r6} = RepeatedTiming[interQ6 @@@ set1, tmax] // Quiet;
```

#### Test results comparison

```
r0 == r1 == r2 == r3 == r4 == r5 == r6 (* True *)
Transpose[{{n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6}, 
   {t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6}}] // Grid  (* above *)
```

Answer (score 6):

For line segments in 2D, you may try also this one:

```
interQ[{u1_?VectorQ, u2_?VectorQ}, {v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ}] := 
  Block[{},
   And[
    Det[{u2 - u1, v1 - u2}] Det[{u2 - u1, v2 - u2}] < 0,
    Det[{v2 - v1, u1 - v2}] Det[{v2 - v1, u2 - v2}] < 0
    ]
   ];
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Thanks for contributing it.  I added your solution to my [comparison](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255876/22158) answer.  I hope you become a regular contributor to this forum.

Answer (score 4):

- The line (AB) intersects the inner part of a non-collinear segment [CD] iff (AB × AC)(AB × AD) < 0 (here × stands for the 2D vector product — which are equal to determinants).
- Moreover, the non-collinear segments [AB] and [BC] intersect iff the line (AB) intersects [CD], and the line (CD) intersects [AB].
- In non-collinear case, the same holds when one allows intersection at endpoints — provided the length of the segments is not 0.
- If one wishes to treat the collinear case too, one needs to special-case the situation when all 4 vector products are 0.
- Similarly when the length may be 0: then the corresponding pair of vector products is 0, so one needs only to special-case this situation.

Anyway, this should be faster by tons than the alternatives.

Comment: In fact, the cases with length 0 are going to give one of the products positive in the first two lines — unless collinear.  So only the case of **all** the products being 0 should be special-cased.  (And then one can check the projections ontp coordinate axes: min(max(A₁,B₁),max(C₁,D₁)) ≥ max(min(A₁,B₁),min(C₁,D₁)); same for the 2nd coordinate.)

Comment: I would like very much to add your method to my answer comparing the various methods.  Can you include a function, like the one in the original post, that takes to `Line`s and returns True or False?  Whether you method is fastest or not, the comparison may be a benefit.

Comment: I do not program Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

We can parametrize the first line segment on the parameter interval $t \in [0,1]$ and the second on the parameter interval $s \in [0,1]$, then use `Solve` to find the intersection, restricting to those two intervals.  If there is no intersection, `Solve` returns an empty list, so the `Length` of the result is zero.  If there is a single point of intersection, `Solve` returns a list containing a list of `Rule`s giving values to the two parameters.  If there is more than one point of intersection, `Solve` returns a list containing a list containing a single `ConditionalExpression` that parametricly describes the resulting segment.

```
intersect[Line[{a_, b_}], Line[{c_, d_}]] := 
  Module[{cap},
    cap = Solve[{a t + b (1 - t) == c s + d (1 - s), 
      0 <= t <= 1, 0 <= s <= 1}, {s, t}, Reals];
    And[Length[cap] == 1, 
      NumberQ[s /. cap[[1]]], 
      NumberQ[t /. cap[[1]]]]
  ]

RepeatedTiming[intersect[Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 1}, {0, -1}}]]]
(*  {0.00048, True}  *)

RepeatedTiming[intersect[Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{1, 2}, {1, 0}}]]]
(*  {0.00047, True}  *)

RepeatedTiming[intersect[Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 2}, {0, 0}}]]]
(*  {0.00047, True}  *)

RepeatedTiming[intersect[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], Line[{{1, 0}, {3, 0}}]]]
(*  {0.002, False}  *)

RepeatedTiming[intersect[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], Line[{{2, 0}, {4, 0}}]]]
(*  {0.002, True}  *)

RepeatedTiming[intersect[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], Line[{{3, 0}, {5, 0}}]]]
(*  {0.001, False}  *)

RepeatedTiming[intersect[Line[{{0, 1}, {2, 1}}], Line[{{1, 0}, {3, 0}}]]]
(*  {0.000037, False}  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
R1[p, q] := m p + (1 - m) q;
R2[p, q] := n p + (1 - n) q;
Test[pts] :=
  And[(0 <= m <= 1), (0 <= n <= 1)] /.
   Solve[R1[pts[[1]], pts[[2]]] == R2[pts[[3]], pts[[4]]], {m, n}];
Draw[pts] :=
  Graphics[{Line[{pts[[1]], pts[[2]]}], Line[{pts[[3]], pts[[4]]}]}];
{Test[#][[1]], Draw[#]} &@RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 2}] // Timing
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would like very much to add your method to my answer comparing the various methods.  Can you include a function, like the one in the original post, that takes to `Line`s and returns True or False?  Whether you method is fastest or not, the comparison may be a benefit.