# How can I get the intersect points of lines connecting different points?

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, data

How can I get the numeric points `{x,y}` where the lines below intersect, please?

```
cvf = {{0.`, 
    0.`}, {-2.5866650924004158`, -1.2251749213103618`}, \
{2.5866650924004153`, 1.2251749213103618`}, {-0.46459988053166823`, 
    3.255060440892003`}, {0.46459988053166823`, -3.255060440892003`}, \
{3.0512649729320835`, -2.0298855195816414`}, {-3.051264972932084`, 
    2.0298855195816414`}};
prePLin[col_, pnt_] := {col, Dashed, 
  Line[{cvf[[pnt]]/2 + RotationMatrix[-90 Degree] . cvf[[pnt]]/2, 
    cvf[[pnt]]/2 + RotationMatrix[90 Degree] . cvf[[pnt]]/2}], 
  Line[{cvf[[pnt + 1]]/2 + 
     RotationMatrix[-90 Degree] . cvf[[pnt + 1]]/2, 
    cvf[[pnt + 1]]/2 + RotationMatrix[90 Degree] . cvf[[pnt + 1]]/2}]}
Graphics[{prePLin[Green, 2], prePLin[Blue, 4], prePLin[Red, 6]}]
```

[image]

I tried [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51391/find-intersection-of-pairs-of-straight-lines) answer

```
LineIntersectionPoint[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] := 
  (Det[{a, b}] (c - d) - Det[{c, d}] (a - b))/Det[{a - b, c - d}]


Tlins[pnt_] := {cvf[[pnt]]/2 + 
   RotationMatrix[-90 Degree] . cvf[[pnt]]/2, 
  cvf[[pnt]]/2 + RotationMatrix[90 Degree] . cvf[[pnt]]/2}
p1 = Table[Tlins[j], {j, {2, 3, 4}}];
p2 = Table[Tlins[j], {j, {5, 6, 7}}];


Graphics[{Line /@ {p1, p2}, Red, PointSize@.05, 
  Point /@ MapThread[LineIntersectionPoint, {p1, p2}]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

but it escapes three points?

Comment: try ``intersections =  Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@  Graphics[{prePLin[Green, 2], prePLin[Blue, 4], prePLin[Red, 6]}]``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    lines = Cases[{prePLin[Green, 2], prePLin[Blue, 4], prePLin[Red, 6]}, 
      Line[__], Infinity]
```

---

Briefly, tuples are created for all extracted lines. This will also have pairs with the same lines that are deleted. After the `RegionIntersection` command is applied there will be `EmptyRegion`s found where lines don't intersect that have to be deleted. Then the duplicated points are removed.

```
ptsI = RegionIntersection @@@ (Tuples[lines, {2}] // 
      DeleteCases[#, {a_, a_}] &) /. EmptyRegion[_] :> Nothing // 
  DeleteDuplicates
```

> ```
> {Point[{{-0.746437, -1.76723}}], Point[{{-1.84023, 0.542052}}], 
>  Point[{{0.746437, 1.76723}}], Point[{{1.84023, -0.542052}}], 
>  Point[{{-1.21104, 1.48783}}], Point[{{1.21104, -1.48783}}]}
> ```

```
Graphics[{{prePLin[Green, 2], prePLin[Blue, 4], prePLin[Red, 6]},
  AbsolutePointSize[6], Red, ptsI}]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Following @bmf 's comment:

Let's say we have `lines` defined as above.

```
{Length@lines, Tuples[lines, {2}] // Length}
```

> {6, 36}

Instead of comparing intersections with 36 pairs of lines, we would like to make tuples in a lower triangularized fashion between the lines. Extracting locations of lines to put into tuples:

```
t = Table[{i, j}, {i, 2, Length@lines}, {j, 1, i - 1}] // 
  Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> ```
> {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 
>   3}, {5, 4}, {6, 1}, {6, 2}, {6, 3}, {6, 4}, {6, 5}}
> ```

```
lineTuples = lines[[#]] & /@ t ;
```

Now there will be no need of deleting duplicates.

```
ptsI = RegionIntersection @@@ lineTuples /. EmptyRegion[_] :> Nothing 

Length@lineTuples (* 15 *)
```

Comment: why does `ptsI` give 12 points? where only 6 are correct?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Syed this is wonderful. I just don't understand the need for `DeleteDuplicates`. I thought that `DeleteCases` would do the trick alone.

Comment: @bmf consider restoring your answer. It shows good usage of Mesh and I was gonna learn more from it. About your comment above, it starts with an embedded line graphic from where I extracted lines and made tuples. I can go a step further and Union the tuples with some effort after which there will be no need of deleting the duplicates. For large lists, it would be a judgement call as to whether to do it first or not, but it is something worth investigating.

Comment: @Syed not sure if you saw it or not, but it was not my answer. As I explained, I borrowed the code developed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/marking-points-of-intersection-between-two-curves/10475#10475). kglr has written a tremendous response, I just applied it. I don't think you'll have issues applying it in this example. Btw, I saw the addition you made to your answer, and many thanks for taking the time to do so. It has been a (+1) from me all along :-)

Comment: @Syed I can restore it, but I don't think it offers much. Yours is much better and the link provided is enough for the other approach I think