# Hightlight all the self-intersections of a Lissajous figure

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

This graph–also known as a Lissajous figure–contains so many self-intersections.How can I highlight them?

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[100 t], Sin[99 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
     PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Too tired to tackle this now, but a hint: for general $n$ (this is case $n=100$) the number of nodes is $2n^2-4n+1$.  They are distributed on a $2n-1$ by $2n-3$ grid, occupying a diagonal pattern (like the white squares on a chessboard).  The key is going to be to find the positions of the lines of the grid.

Comment: Looks like they have x-coordinates `Cos[Pi Range[2 (n - 1) - 1]/(2 (n - 1))]` and y-coordinates `Cos[Pi Range[2 (n - 1) + 1]/(2 (n - 1) + 2)]`.

Comment: A quick idea: extract the `Line[]` objects from a plot of the curve (`Cases[]` is useful here), split any polylines present into simple lines of the form `Line[{pt1, pt2}]`, and then use a [line intersection algorithm](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13712/13714#13714) on the lines produced. Polishing with `FindRoot[]` is optional.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I will start with the most general Lissajous figure, which has a parametric equation as follows:

$$
x(t) = f_a(at+\phi_a) \\
y(t) = f_b(bt+\phi_b) \\
t \in [0,2\pi)
$$

Where:

$$
f_a, f_b \in \{\sin, \cos\} \\
a, b \in \mathbb{N} \\
\phi_a, \phi_b \in [0, 2\pi)
$$

Note that this curve is periodic, so we can "shift" the range of $t$ without changing the curve. Consider one such shift, given by $t \to t'-\frac{\phi_b}{b}$. This gives the new parameterization:

$$
x(t') = f_a\left(a\left(t'-\frac{\phi_b}{b}\right)+\phi_a\right) =f_a\left(at'+\left(\phi_a-\frac{a}{b}\phi_b\right)\right) \\
y(t') = f_b\left(b\left(t'-\frac{\phi_b}{b}\right)+\phi_b\right) = f_b(bt') \\
t \in [0,2\pi)
$$

This shows that we can eliminate one of the phase parameters and still describe the entire set of Lissajous figures. At this point we can also notice that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are related by a phase shift of $\pi/2$, so we can absorb the choice of function into the phase parameter, giving us the simplified equation:

$$
x(t) = \cos(at+\phi) \\
y(t) = \cos(bt) \\
t \in [0,2\pi)
$$

Finally, take $d=\gcd(a,b)$. This means there exist integers $a'$ and $b'$ such that $a=a'd$ and $b=b'd$, so that:

$$
x(t) = \cos(a'(dt)+\phi) \\
y(t) = \cos(b'(dt)) \\
$$

This is the same curve as the one described by $a'$ and $b'$, except covered $d$ times. Therefore we can describe the entire set of Lissajous figures if we restrict ourselves to cases where $a$ and $b$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

---

Now consider a self-crossing of the Lissajous figure. Such a point occurs when two distinct values of $t$ give the same $x,y$ coordinates:

$$
x(t_1)=x(t_2) \to \cos(at_1+\phi) = \cos(at_2+\phi) \\
y(t_1)=y(t_2) \to \cos(bt_1) = \cos(bt_2)
$$

The cosine function is periodic, so one way for two cosines to be equal is for their arguments to differ by a factor of $2\pi$:

$$
\alpha=\beta+2\pi n\to \cos\alpha=\cos\beta
$$

However, the cosine function is also even, so it is also possible for one argument to be the negative of the other (plus a factor of $2\pi$):

$$
\alpha=-\beta+2\pi n\to \cos\alpha=\cos\beta
$$

Note that at all of the self-crossings, one branch of the curve is moving in an "upwards" diagonal direction and the other is moving in a "downwards" diagonal direction. This means that one of $x$ or $y$ must obey the "negated" equality, so we have one of:

$$
at_1+\phi = at_2+\phi+2\pi n \\
bt_1 = -(bt_2)+2\pi m \\
\textrm{or} \\
at_1+\phi = -(at_2+\phi) + 2\pi n\\
bt_1 = bt_2 + 2\pi m
$$

These two systems of equations are linear in $t_1$ and $t_2$ so they each have a unique solution:

$$
t_1 = \left(\frac{n}{a}+\frac{m}{b}\right)\pi - \frac{\phi}{a} \\
t_2 = \left(\frac{n}{a}-\frac{m}{b}\right)\pi - \frac{\phi}{a} \\
\textrm{or} \\
t_1 = \left(\frac{n}{a}+\frac{m}{b}\right)\pi \\
t_2 = \left(-\frac{n}{a}+\frac{m}{b}\right)\pi
$$

This gives the following sets of intersection points:

$$
(x,y) = \left(\cos\left(n\pi + \frac{a}{b}m\pi\right), \cos\left(\frac{b}{a}n\pi + m\pi - \frac{b}{a}\phi)\right)\right) \\
0\le n\le a-1,\quad1 \le m \le b-1\\
\textrm{and} \\
(x,y) = \left(\cos\left(n\pi + \frac{a}{b}m\pi + \phi\right), \cos\left(\frac{b}{a}n\pi + m\pi\right)\right) \\
1\le n\le a-1,\quad0 \le m \le b-1
$$

Plotting these points in Mathematica:

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{Cos[a t + ϕ], Cos[b t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
    PlotLabel -> {a, b}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
      Table[Point[{Cos[(n + a/b m)Pi], Cos[(b/a n + m)Pi - b/a ϕ]}],
        {n, a}, {m, b - 1}],
     Table[Point[{Cos[(n + a/b m)Pi + ϕ], Cos[(b/a n + m)Pi]}],
        {n, a - 1}, {m, b}]
    }
   ],
  {{a, 5}, 2, 20, 1},
  {{b, 4}, Select[Range[a], CoprimeQ[a, #] &]},
  {{ϕ, Pi/10}, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! and really fast as well! (+1)

Comment: @Marco Much faster if you use `2.`.

Comment: @2012rcampion You code comes first , but it's a pity that it becomes slow when n is large.

Comment: I invite you to answer my related question.and it may be more challenging than this one. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83244/count-the-number-of-regions-make-by-lissajous-curve

Comment: @Wate Actually the answer to that one is quite simple: the number of intersections for $a$ and $b$ both odd is $(a-1)(b-1)/2$ and the number of intersections in the other cases is $2ab-(a+b)$.  The number of regions is simply the number of intersections plus one (every time you close a curve by intersection, you split a previous region into two, and you start with one region).

Comment: Well, I wish I had another (+1) to give! I was impressed by your answer yesterday, but then I came back today to find this! It was a real pleasure to read, and a feast for the eyes as well. I haven't been around very long on MMA.SE, but nonetheless this is one of the best answers I have seen so far!

Comment: @Marco After all those upvotes (finally hit the daily rep limit, woot), I felt the question deserved more than the ten minutes I gave it!

Comment: The most excellent answer I have seen.:)

Comment: How could you get your conclusion:when Divsible[a,b]==False,the number of intersections for a and b both odd is (a−1)(b−1)/2 and the number of intersections in the other cases is 2ab−(a+b)?I get a formula depend on m,n but failed when a and b both odd.Meanwhile my formula is just more complex than yours.:(

Comment: @Wate For the odd-even case, the grid is $2a-1$ by $2b-1$, so there are $(2a-1)(2b-1)$ grid nodes, half (less one) of which are filled: $$[(2a-1)(2b-1)-1]/2=(4ab-2a-2b+1-1)/2=2ab-(a+b)$$  For the odd-odd case, the grid is only half-filled: $a-1$ by $b-1$.  This time the grid has even dimensions, so the number of intersections is exactly half: $(a-1)(b-1)/2$.

Comment: @Wate (At least, that's what I should have done.  What I really did was to use `Count[_, _Point, Infinity]` on my table of plots, then pass the counts to `Rationalize@Chop@Fit[_, {1, a, b, a b}, {a, b}]`.)

Comment: Umm,I think I should test it for large {a,b}s.

Comment: @Wate Test what?

Comment: My formula is modifiedfloor[n_] := Floor[n] - Boole[IntegerQ[n]]*Sum[modifiedfloor[2*n - 1/2 - (n*k)/m] - Ceiling[-(1/2) + (n*k)/m] + 1, {k, 1, m - 1}] + 
   Sum[modifiedfloor[2*m - 1/2 - (m*k)/n] - Ceiling[-(1/2) + (m*k)/n] + 1, {k, 1, n - 1}] ,which is true when {Sin[m t],Sin[n t]} 0<=t<2Pi && m,n is odd && Divisible[m,n]==False.But how can I simplify it into your form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23750/discussion-between-2012rcampion-and-watesoyan).

Comment: N.B. These intersection points are related to what are now termed [Padua points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padua_points).

Comment: When I use the "final result" above, I get the graphic at https://pasteboard.co/FFq5on8DU4sR.jpg, not the one you posted. Is there an error in the MMA code you posted? Second question: How would you modify this for Lissajous curves using $\cos$ instead of $\sin$ (with a phase adjustment). Unbelievably great answer, BTW.

Comment: @2012rcampion Any comments on the comment above? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @rogerl You are right, it is definitely broken... probably made a typo when formatting the code.

Comment: @2012rcampion So do you have any idea what is wrong, or am I on my own :)

Answer (score 18):

One way (whew, there are a lot of intersections! -- here's a shorter version):

```
sol = NSolve[{Sin[10 t], Sin[9 t]} == ({Sin[10 t], Sin[9 t]} /. t -> s) && 
    0 <= t < s < 2 Pi, {t, s}];

ParametricPlot[{Sin[10 t], Sin[9 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{Sin[10 t], Sin[9 t]} /. sol]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(`{Sin[100 t], Sin[99 t]}` will take a lot longer.)

**General solution via *Mathematica* that is not too slow**

`Solve` returns solutions in the form `ConditionalExpression`, and the condition can be used to generate the values `{m, n}` for each point of intersection (via `Solve` inside `Block`).

```
gensols = Cases[
   Solve[(-a t + a s == 2 Pi m || a t + a s == Pi + 2 Pi m) &&
          (b t - b s == 2 Pi n || b t + b s == Pi + 2 Pi n) && 
     a > b > 0 && {a, b, m, n} ∈ Integers && 
     0 <= t < s < 2 Pi, {s, t}],
   HoldPattern[t -> t0_] :> {t -> t0}, 2];

Block[{a = 100, b = 99},
   pts = Flatten[
     Hold[{Sin[a t], Sin[b t]} /. Solve[Last[t], {m, n}]] /. gensols // ReleaseHold,
     1]
   ] // Length // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {1.55879, 19601}  *)


ParametricPlot[{Sin[100 t], Sin[99 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.0015]}, PlotPoints -> 3000,
 Epilog -> {GraphicsComplex[N@pts, {Red, PointSize[0.003], Point[Range@Length@pts]}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: 19,601 intersections if my math is correct.

Comment: It's a pity that NSolve takes a very long time.

Comment: @WateSoyan Well, 20K points are a lot to track down and `NSolve` might be converting the trig. eqns. to polynomial ones -- ouch. The difference between solving (this answer) and having been solved (rcampion2012's) is to be expected.  You must be making a pretty big poster to show all those points! :)

Comment: @Michael E2 I have posted my answer below,purely based on Solve.

Comment: @WateSoyan To me it's a pity that I preferred to figure out how to get *Mathematica* to solve the problem, than to solve it mathematically myself, like rcampion2012.  (But then again, this site *is* about how to use *M*.)

Comment: @2012rcampion I keep getting your username reversed -- sorry about that!

Comment: I invite you to answer my related question.and it may be more challenging than this one.http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83244/count-the-number-of-regions-make-by-lissajous-curve

Answer (score 12):

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

eps = 1/1000000;    
pp = ParametricPlot[{Sin[10 t], Sin[9 t]}, {t, eps, 2 π}];
intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp];

Show[pp, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@intersections}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[ParametricPlot[{Sin[100 t], Sin[99 t]}, 
    {t, eps, 2 π}]] // Length // Timing
```

> {0.078125, 20330}

```
Row[Show[plt = ParametricPlot[{Sin[# t], Sin[(# - 1) t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}], 
    ImageSize -> 300, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.2/#], 
      Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt]}] & /@ {5, 10, 20, 50}]
```

[image]

See also: [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13714/125) linked in @Guesswhoitis's comment above.

Comment: Now I remember that function!  +1.

Comment: @Michael, thank you for the vote.

Comment: Glad to see my idea works. :)

Comment: @J.M, sorry  I was distracted by `Cases[...]` in your comment above and failed to click the link you provided. Yes, it does work; and directly on the graphics input without the extra need to extract the lines.

Comment: Yes, not needing to explicitly extract the lines was a big surprise. :)

Comment: @kguler The function you use is so efficient,where did you find it?

Comment: @WateSoyan,  it came up as one of the search results from ``??*`*Intersections*``.

Comment: I invite you to answer my related question.and it may be more challenging than this one. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83244/count-the-number-of-regions-make-by-lissajous-curve

Comment: @kguler Can you tell me how to use a new function like ``Graphics`Mesh`GeometryPlot`` ? I don't get any useful infomation from `??`

Comment: @Wate, since these functions are undocumented, it is a matter of luck + trial/error to discover their syntax information. I haven't used the function `GeometryPlot` before. In some cases, you can pass `junk` as an argument to the function, and if you are lucky, you get an error message that suggests what kind of input is expected.  So, trying ``Graphics`Mesh`GeometryPlot[blah]`` gives _blah was encountered where a Graphics primitive or directive was 
expected_. So, there you have it: `Graphics`Mesh`GeometryPlot[ Polygon@{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}},  PlotStyle -> Red]` works!

Comment: ... How is this function different from `Graphics` or `Plot`?  Well...  perhaps: it has some options that `Graphics` does not; and, whereas `Plot` takes a function as the first argument, this one takes a graphics primitive...

Answer (score 1):

I find a workaround which can find all that exact self-intersections:

```
    sol = Solve[(100 (t1 - t2) == 2 k1 \[Or] 
          100 (t1 + t2) == (2 k1 + 1)) && (99 (t1 - t2) == 2 k2 \[Or] 
          99 (t1 + t2) == (2 k2 + 1)), {t1, t2}];
   Flatten[({t1, t2} /. # /. Solve[(0 <= t1 < t2 < 2) /. #, {k1, k2}, Integers]) & /@ sol, 1]
```

Comment: You have slightly more than twice as many solutions as rcampion2012.  I think you want `Flatten[({t1, t2} /. # /.  Solve[(0 <= t1 < t2 < 2) /. #, {k1, k2}, Integers]) & /@ sol, 1]` to get each solution exactly once. (I was working along similar lines, but I was trying to get the solution even faster.)

Comment: @Michael E2 Yeah,I forgot to check it.