# Count the number of regions made by Lissajous curve

Tags: plotting, regions, counting

How many disconnected regions does Lissajous curve divide the plane into?

For example: 
 Let

```
g = ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

The number of disconnected regions made by curve `g` is 3.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Seems like a mathematics question.  Isn't it just 2 plus the number of crossings, provided it's a closed curve with simple crossings?

Comment: Not sure how general this is: perhaps ``Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];1 + Length@  Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[
     ParametricPlot[{Sin[# t], Sin[ (# - 1) t]}, {t, 0,  2 Pi }]] & /@ {2, 3, 4, 5}``?

Comment: @kguler Oh,guy,why the answer of Length@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 t], Sin[(2 - 1) t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]] is 2?But it should be 1 .Somthing wrong?

Comment: @WateSoyan, for a closed curve the starting  point is also an intersection (it intersects with the ending point).

Comment: @kguler I wonder about the reliability of that hypothesis: ``Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Graphics[Line@Table[{Sin[2 t], Sin[(2 - 1) t]}, {t, 0., 2. Pi, 2. Pi/100}]]]`` gives one point -- the hypothesis seems to rely some approximate error made by `ParametricPlot` so that the two points are not duplicates.  An offset noncommensurable with `Pi` might fix it (e.g. `t -> t - 1`).

Comment: @MichaelE2, great point;  I also need to fix the answer in OP's other question. Thank you !

Comment: @kguler You're very welcome!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't like to think too much :P

```
Manipulate[
 {#, Composition[
      # - 1 &,
      Length,
      Union,
      Flatten,
      MorphologicalComponents,
      Binarize,
      Rasterize
      ]@#} &@
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[ n t], Sin[m t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick]
 , {n, 2, 10, 1}, {m, 1, 9, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: A similar method was used to count the self-intersections of Lissajous curve.

Comment: @WateSoyan it depends on what do you mean by similar, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Your code is so applicable that I benefit a lot from it.:)

Comment: You might want to add imagesize, which is a function of n and m

Answer (score 11):

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
eps = 1/100000000;
Manipulate[Labeled[plt = ParametricPlot[{Sin[n t], Sin[(n - 1) t]}, {t, eps, 2 Pi},
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick]; plt /. Line -> Polygon, 
  Grid[{{"n", "p"}, {n, 2 + Length@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt]}}, 
       ItemStyle -> Directive[16, "Panel"]], Top], {n, 2, 10, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your method is nice.Thank you.But could you explain why your code should return a true result?

Comment: @WateSoyan,  rough/raw intuition: every time a simple curve intersects itself it creates a new _region/polygon_  (try it with pen and paper).

Comment: Yes,in this cases, it's true.But I think it's not always be true in other cases.

Comment: By any chance, @Wate, are you in any way familiar with Euler's $v-e+f=2$?

Comment: @Wate I think it's always be true in all cases.

Comment: @2012rcampion Umm,I agree that every time a curve intersects itself it creates a new region,but the number of the regions is not always depend on the number of self-intersections,in other words if we face with a flower-like curve,we should consider the multiplicities of self-intersections.

Comment: @Wate Every time you pass through a previous intersection, you add one new intersection and one new region.  I still think it holds.

Comment: Euler's formula will still hold for roses; if for instance we consider the three-petaled case, I count one vertex (the triple point) and three edges (the three petals), after which substituting into Euler's formula should yield four regions.

Comment: However, @Wate, you only asked about Lissajous curves in the question; these curves will only exhibit double nodes, so kguler's counting strategy works here. If you want to ask about rosettes instead, ask a new question.