# How do you find the self-intersection points of a single parametric trigonometric function?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, intersection

How do you use `Solve` or `FindRoot` or other *Mathematica* functions to find the points at which the graph of ${\bf a}(t) = 3 \cos (3.3 \pi t)\hat{\bf x} + (\sin (4 \pi t) + 4 t) \hat{\bf y}$ intersects itself?

```
a[t_] := 3 Cos[33/10 Pi t]*{1, 0} + (Sin[4 Pi t] + 4 t)*{0, 1};
ParametricPlot[a[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: And  please try to learn at least the basics of Mathematica syntax

Comment: This is a very good problem, which is not a duplicate of others, and has a non-trivial solution.  It should not be closed.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ansering this question migth be an interesting exercise, however it doesn't  address a (_Mathematica_- lly) new problem. . There were at least a few other quite analogical questions on MSE. And finally the OP doesn't formulated a well - posed question, just " do it for me", no effort on his side.  Such questions  make this site disordered.

Comment: @Artes:  Implied in the problem is "How to solve this using *Mathematica*"?  I agree, the poser showed no work, but the problem is rather difficult and he/she might have said that any number of obvious techniques don't work.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Certainly, I assume it is related to _Mathematica_. Just check if answers to  the  linked post don't work here. I haven't tried but I'm quite sure at least two of those methods work perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

`FindRoot` is used to find the intersection values of the parameter. Starting values for `FindRoot` are determined by annotating parameter milestones along the curve.

```
intersect[1] = FindRoot[{
   3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t1] == 3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t2],
   Sin[4 Pi t1] + 4 t1 == Sin[4 Pi t2] + 4 t2},
  {{t1, .15}, {t2, .45}}]

(* {t1 -> 0.134804, t2 -> 0.471257} *)

intersect[2] = FindRoot[{
   3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t1] == 3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t2],
   Sin[4 Pi t1] + 4 t1 == Sin[4 Pi t2] + 4 t2},
  {{t1, 1.05}, {t2, 1.38}}]

(* {t1 -> 1.03533, t2 -> 1.38891} *)

intersect[3] = FindRoot[{
   3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t1] == 3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t2],
   Sin[4 Pi t1] + 4 t1 == Sin[4 Pi t2] + 4 t2},
  {{t1, 1.65}, {t2, 1.98}}]

(* {t1 -> 1.66478, t2 -> 1.97158} *)

ParametricPlot[
 {3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t], Sin[4 Pi t] + 4 t},
 {t, 0, 2},
 ColorFunction ->
  (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &),
 Epilog -> {
   AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Table[
    Tooltip[
     Point[ (* 
      milestones used to determine starting values for FindRoot *)
      {3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t], Sin[4 Pi t] + 4 t}],
     t],
    {t, 0, 2, .1}],
   Red,
   Table[
    Tooltip[
     Point[ (* 
      intersection points *)
      {3 Cos[33/10 Pi* t1], 
        Sin[4 Pi t1] + 4 t1} /.
       intersect[n]],
     ToString[intersect[n]]],
    {n, 3}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: neat...like metaphor of milestones on a path also...+1 of course :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not at all suggesting that things should be done this way, since it will be decidedly slow, and the undocumented [`FindIntersections`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86907/29734) function is [apparently a little unreliable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/graphicsmeshfindintersections-fails-to-detect-intersections), but I thought the following method was cute, and we will give `FindIntersections` every change to succeed. This method also has the distinction of not requiring guesses that can be fed to `FindRoot`, and in fact it can be used to *generate* good guesses for using `FindRoot`. In any case, here it is.

Let's take as our function

```
r[t_] = {3 Cos[33 π t/10], Sin[4 π t] + 4 t};
```

### Step 1: Generate the zero-contours of `r[t1] - r[t2]`

The two components of `r` must simultaneously and independently by equal. In other words, it must be true that

```
0 == r[t1] - r[t2] // First
```

and

```
0 == r[t1] - r[t2] // Last
```

for `t1 != t2`. Individually, we can think of each of these equations as defining the zero-contours of a function `f[t1, t2]`. In order to satisfy these equations simultaneously, we will look for the intersections between the contours of the two different component functions. **This is the main insight.** So, we generate the `ContourPlot`s:

```
pl = Show[
  MapThread[
    ContourPlot[#1
      , {t1, 0, 5}, {t2, 0, 5}
      , Contours -> {0}
      , RegionFunction -> Function[#1 > #2]
      , ContourStyle -> #2
      , ContourShading -> False
      , PlotPoints -> 20] &
    , {r[t1] - r[t2], {Blue, Red}}]
 ]
```

resulting in

[image]

We have chosen to use `RegionFunction -> Function[#1 > #2]` because `t1` and `t2` are basically dummy variables.

Now, we care about where the blue curves intersect the red curves, because it is at those points that both components of `r[t1] - r[t2]` are simultaneously zero. We want to try to cut out any extra intersections, like the ones between the blue curves. For this, we modify the code above to include instead

```
RegionFunction -> Function[#1 > #2 && Abs[#1 - #2] < 0.6]
```

We had to come up with the number `0.6` by hand, of course. This method is not without some necessary fiddling. The result is

[image]

### Step 2: Find the intersections

We use an undocumented function to find those intersections:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];
intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp];
Show[pp, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.017], Point /@ intersections}]
```

resulting in

[image]

### Step 3: Feed the results to `FindRoot`

The answers are already pretty good, but we can polish them by using them as the guesses for `FindRoot`:

```
times = FindRoot[Thread[r[t1] == r[t2]], Transpose[{{t1, t2}, #}]] & /@ intersections
(* {{t1 -> 0.471257, t2 -> 0.134804}, {t1 -> 1.38891, t2 -> 1.03533}
  , {t1 -> 1.97158, t2 -> 1.66478}, {t1 -> 2.90891, t2 -> 2.54563}
  , {t1 -> 3.45833, t2 -> 3.20833}, {t1 -> 4.42628, t2 -> 4.05857}
  , {t1 -> 4.88051, t2 -> 4.81646}} *)
```

### Step 4: Check the results

In order to make sure that each pair `{t1, t2}` corresponds to the same intersection, and that we have found them all, and that they are correct, we can plot the points together with the original curve:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[r[t]
     , {t, 0, 5}
     , Epilog -> {PointSize[0.07], Red, Point@r[#] /. times[[kk]]}
     ] & /@ {t1, t2} // GraphicsRow
 , {kk, 1, Length@times, 1}]
```

resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

First, note that the techniques on the "[possible duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph)" link do not work directly:

```
sol = t /. {ToRules@
    Reduce[
      3 Cos[3.3 \[Pi] t] == 3 Cos[3.3 \[Pi] (t + x)] &&
      Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 4 t == Sin[4 \[Pi] (t + x)] + 4 (t + x) &&
      0 < t < 4 \[Pi] &&
      0 < x < 2 \[Pi], 
{t, x}]}
```

> Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or \
>   the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers \
>   present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce \
>   require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the \
>   system may help

**Here's the solution**:

Consider first the position in the $\hat{\bf x}$ (horizontal) direction:

The vertical red line marks the time $t0 = 1/3.3$, i.e., the first minimum of the cosine function.  The two times corresponding to the intersection point must be of the form $t1 = t0 - dt = 1/3.3 - dt$ and $t2 = t0 + dt = 1/3.3 + dt$, for some unknown $dt$, i.e., the times are symmetric with respect to the first minimum of the cosine function at $t0$.

[image]

Then you solve for the unknown $dt$ by considering the $\hat{\bf y}$ (vertical) position:

```
FindRoot[Sin[4 \[Pi] (1/3.3 + dt)] + 4 (1/3.3 + dt) == 
         Sin[4 \[Pi] (1/3.3 - dt)] + 4 (1/3.3 - dt), 
         {dt, .5}]
```

which yields $dt = 0.168227$.

Then you go back to the form of ${\bf a}(t)$ and plug in these new times:

```
{3 Cos[3.3 \[Pi] t] , (Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 4 t)} /. t -> 1/3.3 + 0.168227
```

and

```
{3 Cos[3.3 \[Pi] t] , (Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 4 t)} /. t -> 1/3.3 - 0.168227
```

each of which gives a time which yields the location of the intersection point:

{0.517172, 1.53164}

```
ParametricPlot[{3 Cos[3.3 \[Pi] t] , (Sin[4 \[Pi] t] + 4 t)}, 
     {t, 0, 2},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.05], Point[{0.51717, 1.53164}]}]
```

[image]

You can find other intersection points by choosing successive peaks or valleys of the (horizontal) cosine function, i.e., at $k/3.3$ where $k$ is an integer.

(The problem gets a bit trickier when the two solution times are *not* symmetric with respect to an extremum of the cosine function because there are non-loops in the parametric plot, but are of the form $t1 = k/3.3 + dt$ and $t2 = k/3.3 - (2 \pi + dt)$.)

At the core, I suspect the "possible duplicate" methods do not work here because `Reduce` has problems finding solutions in two variables whereas `FindRoot` works well with just one variable.

Answer (score 4):

Set up:

```
p[t_] := {3 Cos[3.3 Pi t], Sin[4 Pi t] + 4 t}
```

Choosing starting values:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[p[t], {t, 0, 2}], 
  Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[p[j]]}]], {j, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Using `FindRoot` and testing:

```
es = {0.135, 1.035, 1.67}
is = p[s] /. (FindRoot[p[s] == p[s + t], {{s, #}, {t, 0.25}}] & /@ es)
ParametricPlot[p[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[is]}]
```

Points: {{0.517162, 1.53164}, {-0.777101, 4.57088}, {-0.0586081, 7.53675}}

[image]