# How to get Lissajous curve like the following gif

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, list-manipulation, animation

parameter equation $x= \sin(m t)$, $y= \sin (nt)$,(fix $m=13$, $n=18$ not to change)

I need the picture show the generation of the curve.(start from one point to the final curve like you draw it manually )

In fact,I just want to know how to generate a curve continuously like the gif show[image]

Comment: Where are you stuck? Manipulate and ParametricPlot seem to be an obvious way to go, or?

Comment: Searching for Mathematica Lissajous reveals [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83118/7167) which may be a duplicate.

Comment: i want to form the curve from one point to the final picture like the gif show  @  bobthechemist

Comment: i don't know how to get the effect like the picture shows(from one point to the final picture)@Kuba♦

Comment: Side note: this GIF is from http://www.matrix67.com/blog/archives/6947 . Then, what have you tried?

Comment: i just want to know how to generate a curve from one point continuously to the final curve.@xzczd

Comment: @kuba has mentioned the necessary function for making the animation, and coding this in _Mathematica_ is straightforward. As I've asked in my last comment, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm asking you to show how you tried them, so we can give you pointed advice.

Comment: sorry and i've known where i was wrong, thanks again@xzczd

Answer (score 3):

```
Animate[
ParametricPlot[{Sin[13 t], Sin[18 t]}, {t, 0, tf}],
{tf, 0, 10}]
```