# How to compile Heike's winding number function?

Tags: graphics, compile, geometry

[Heike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/528/intersecting-graphics) gave the following function for winding number:

```
winding[poly_, pt_] :=  
Round[(Total@Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 
   2 Pi, -Pi]/2./Pi)]
```

I attempted to compile it as follows:

```
winding2 := Compile[{{poly, _Real, 2}, {pt, _Real, 1}},   
Round[(Total@Mod[(# - RotateRight[#]) &@(ArcTan @@ (pt - #) & /@ poly), 
    2 Pi, -Pi]/2./Pi)]]
```

Applied to the following simple problem, the compiled version gives error messages:

```
poly = {{0., 0.}, {10., 0.}, {10., 6.}, {0, 6}, {0., 0.}};
pt = {5., 3.}; 
winding2[poly, pt]
```

The error messages include:

```
Compile::cpapot: Compilation of ArcTan@@(ptCompile`GetElement[poly,System`Private`CompileSymbol[0]]) 
is not supported for the function argument ArcTan. The only function arguments supported are 
Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression 6.283185307179586` should be a machine-size integer. >>
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1;
proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You can also use the undocumented ``Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber`` which seems to be just as fast as the compiled version.

Comment: In version 11.3, ``Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber`` seems to have been moved to ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber``.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, if you use `:=` in your assignment, then the compilation is not done instantly but every time you call `winding2`. That's btw the reason why you get the error message when you try to call the function because it is not compiled until then and the error is a compilation error.

Secondly, as the error messages sais, `@@` can only be used with `Times`, `Plus` or `List`, so you have to expand this part:

```
winding2 = 
 Compile[{{poly, _Real, 2}, {pt, _Real, 1}}, 
  Round[Total@Mod[# - RotateRight[#] &@(ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &@
    (Transpose@poly - pt)), 2 Pi, -Pi]/(2. Pi)]
 ]
```

Seems to work pretty smoothly

[image]

And here the code:

```
winding2 = 
  Compile[{{poly, _Real, 2}, {pt, _Real, 1}}, 
   0 != Round[
     Total@Mod[# - 
           RotateRight[#] &@(ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &@(Transpose@
              poly - pt)), 2 Pi, -Pi]/(2. Pi)], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

With[{gr = 
   RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> All, 
    FrameTicks -> None, PlotPoints -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
    PlotStyle -> RGBColor[14/15, 232/255, 71/85], 
    MeshStyle -> RGBColor[88/255, 22/51, 39/85]]}, 
 DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}, polyPts}, 
  polyPts = 
   gr[[1, 1, #]] & /@ 
    Flatten[Cases[gr, Polygon[pts__] :> Sequence[pts], Infinity], 1];
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
   Dynamic@Show[gr, 
     Graphics[{Opacity[.5], RGBColor[38/255, 139/255, 14/17], 
       Polygon[Pick[polyPts, winding2[#, pt] & /@ polyPts]]}]]]]]
```

Comment: Nice animation (+1).  A bit faster: `0 != Round[Total@Mod[# - RotateRight[#] &@(ArcTan[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &@(Transpose@poly - pt)), 2 Pi, -Pi]/(2. Pi)]`.  You might want `0 !=` instead of `1  ==`, in case the winding number is `-1`.  The OP can worry about an even/odd rule or whether to use the winding number itself, instead of inside/outside the polygon.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, I edited my post. Honestly, I haven't barely looked at the implementation of Heike. I just saw the bug and fixed this. Thanks, for looking in more detail at this.