# How to decompose a self intersecting polygon into simple polygons?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

**I want to divide a self intersecting polygon into simple polygons with [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number).**

For example `poly = Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, -1}, {-3/10, 0}, {3/10, 0}, {-1, -1}}]`

[image]

It should be divided into two parts: the **gray part(winding=1)** and the **darker part(winding=2)**.

So I want to get a list like this:

```
{
    {2,Polygon[{{-3/10,0},{0,-3/13},{3/10,0}}]},
    {1,Polygon[{{3/10,0},{0,-3/13},{1,-1},{0,1},{-1,-1},{0,-3/13},{-3/10,0}}]}
}
```

In other words, I would like a function `polyDecompose` which takes as input a `Polygon` and returns a list of `{windingnumber,Polygon[...]}`.

Another example, a pentagram can be divided into 5 parts with winding number 1 and 1 part with winding number 2.

`Polygon[Table[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,0,4 Pi,(4 Pi)/5}]]//Graphics`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind using undocumented, internal functions, then the following returns the desired polygons without the winding numbers:

```
Graphics`PolygonUtils`SimplePolygonPartition[
    Polygon@{{0,1},{1,-1},{-3/10,0},{3/10,0},{-1,-1}}
]
```

> {Polygon[{{-0.3, 0.}, {2.77556*10^-17, -0.230769}, {0.3, 0.}}], 
>    Polygon[{{0.3, 0.}, {2.77556*10^-17, -0.230769}, {1., -1.}, {0., 
>       1.}, {-1., -1.}, {2.77556*10^-17, -0.230769}, {-0.3, 0.}}]}

Comment: ```Polygon[Table[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,0,4 Pi,(4 Pi)/5}]]//Graphics`PolygonUtils`SimplePolygonPartition``` No response.

Comment: @GalAster This works: ``Block[{Region`Mesh`IntersectionFreeSegmentsQ},Polygon[Table[{Cos[t],Sin[t]},{t,0,4 Pi,(4 Pi)/5}]]//Graphics`PolygonUtils`SimplePolygonPartition]``

Comment: wow, that's cool, but I can't understand the `Block` here.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer, but it might be helpful to have a function that computes the winding number of a point `x` in the plane with respect to the closed polygon `poly` (represented by a sequence of points with first and last point coinciding).

```
windingnumber = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {poly, _Real, 2}},
   Block[{wn, p1, p2, q1, q2, x1, x2},
    wn = 0;
    x1 = Compile`GetElement[x, 1];
    x2 = Compile`GetElement[x, 2];

    Do[
     p1 = Compile`GetElement[poly, i, 1];
     p2 = Compile`GetElement[poly, i, 2];
     q1 = Compile`GetElement[poly, i + 1, 1];
     q2 = Compile`GetElement[poly, i + 1, 2];
     If[p2 <= x2,
      If[q2 > x2,(* possible upcrossing *)

       If[(q1 - p1) (x2 - p2) - (q2 - p2) (x1 - p1) > 0, wn++]
       ],
      If[q2 <= x2,(* possible downcrossing *)

       If[(q1 - p1) (x2 - p2) - (q2 - p2) (x1 - p1) < 0, wn--]]
      ],
     {i, 1, Length[poly] - 1}];
    wn
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Here a simple usage example:

```
γ = t \[Function] {Cos[t], Sin[t]} + 0.5 {Cos[-6 t], Sin[-6 t]};
poly = γ /@ Subdivide[-Pi, Pi, 200];
pts = Outer[List, Subdivide[-1.5, 1.5, 600],Subdivide[-1.5, 1.5, 600]];
ArrayPlot@Rescale@windingnumber[pts, poly]
```

[image]

Comment: The syntax is reversed, but you could also use the internal function ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber`` to find the winding number.

Comment: But mine is faster... ;)

Comment: On OSX with M11.3, I find that yours is slower? What is your configuration?

Comment: M11.3, macOS 10.13.4, i7 4980HQ @ 2,8 GHz, 16GB DDR3 RAM @1600 Mhz. Code runs 5 times faster here. This is not the first time that we get quite different timings.

Comment: Also related: Heike's algorithm [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2092/731), which was written in compiled form by halirutan [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28547/731). In the latter, rm -rf also points to ``Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber``. It may be the same as ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber``. +1

Comment: @C.E. In version 11.3, ``Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber`` seems to be nonexistent. It has probably been moved to ``Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber``.

Comment: @CarlWoll Did you try that with a long list of points in a listable fashion like `Partition[
 Graphics`PolygonUtils`PointWindingNumber[poly, Flatten[pts, 1]], 
 Dimensions[pts][[2]]]`?