# Cropping a Voronoi diagram

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

Someone know how can I get the correct crop of this Voronoi image using `RegionFunction`?
[image: Voronoi Diagram]

As you can see, there is a lot of undesired white regions inside the left polygon.
Some clue on how to correct it? Here is the code using `PointInPoly` and `RegionFunction`:

```
PointInPoly[{x_, y_}, poly_List] := 
 Module[{i, j, c = False, npol = Length[poly]}, 
  For[i = 1; j = npol, i <= npol, j = i++, 
   If[((((poly[[i, 2]] <= y) && (y < 
             poly[[j, 2]])) || ((poly[[j, 2]] <= y) && (y < 
             poly[[i, 2]]))) && (x < (poly[[j, 1]] - 
             poly[[i, 1]])*(y - poly[[i, 2]])/(poly[[j, 2]] - 
              poly[[i, 2]]) + poly[[i, 1]])), c = ¬ c];];
  c]

pts=MapIndexed[Flatten[{##}]&,RandomReal[{0,1},{20,2}]];

poli={0.5,0.5}+#&/@Table[0.3{Cos[2π k/6],Sin[2π k/6]},{k,0,6}];
opt={ColorFunction->Hue
    ,InterpolationOrder->0
    ,ImageSize->500
    ,PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}}
    ,Epilog->{PointSize[.01],Point[Most/@pts],Line[poli]}
    };

g1=ListDensityPlot[pts
    ,Sequence@@opt
    ,RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},PointInPoly[{x, y}, poli]]
    ];

g2=ListDensityPlot[pts
    ,Sequence@@opt
    ];

GraphicsRow@{g1, g2}
```

Important point, I can't use image manipulate functions.

What I really need is the list of polygons inside the cropped area. I get it using `g1[[1]]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### V10 way

```
m = VoronoiMesh @ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}];
p = Table[{Cos[i], Sin[i]}, {i, Pi/3., 2 Pi, Pi/3}] // Polygon // DiscretizeGraphics;
```

[image]

```
DeleteCases[
  RegionIntersection[DiscretizeGraphics@#, p] & /@  MeshPrimitives[m, 2],
  _RegionIntersection
 ] // RegionPlot[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &
```

[image]

---

### Old stuff

Using [`PolygonIntersection` introduced here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13715/5478):

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

g2 = ListDensityPlot[pts, Sequence @@ opt];

po = Cases[
           Normal @ g2,
           Polygon[x_, y__] :> x,
           Infinity];

po2 = PolygonIntersection[Polygon/@{poli, #}, AllTriangles->False] & /@ po /. 
                                                          Polygon[{{}}] -> Sequence[];

GraphicsRow[{
     Graphics[{Hue /@ Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[po2] - 1)], po2} // Transpose],
     g2}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Coordinates of vertices you are looking for are in `po2`, you can just remove `Polygon` heads from inside.

This is undocumented function but the method will work for each function calculating graphics intersection. I just used it because it is short.

Comment: Tks @Cuba. Exactly what I need. I'll wait just for respect the protocol. :)

Comment: @Murta I'm glad it works as you want it to work. Of course, no need to hurry. :)