# Making a Voronoi diagram bounded by the convex hull

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

Consider the following:

```
SeedRandom["blah"];
pts = RandomReal[1, {50, 2}];

{cm = ConvexHullMesh[pts],
 vm = VoronoiMesh[pts, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Small], Point[pts]}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: convex hull and Voronoi diagram]

I want to generate the Voronoi diagram bounded by the convex hull. I had tried using `RegionIntersection` but all I get is the original convex hull. Is there a way to cut out the parts of the Voronoi diagram that are outside the convex hull, such that the result is still a `MeshRegion` object?

Comment: At least closely related: [Cropping Voronoi diagram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31187/5478)

Answer (score 14):

Here is an approach that should get you there:

```
SeedRandom["blah"]; pts = RandomReal[1, {50, 2}];
cm = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Small], Point[pts]}];
```

The idea is to find the `RegionIntersection` of the Voronoi cells with the convex hull of the sites, and to combine these regions to get the Voronoi diagram bounded by the convex hull:

```
prim = MeshPrimitives[vm, 2];
allreg = RegionIntersection[cm, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ #] & /@ prim;
allprim = Map[MeshPrimitives[#, 2] &, allreg][[All, 1]];
```

We now have the Voronoi cells bounded by the convex hull. Let's visualize it:

```
gr = Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Black], RandomColor[], #} & /@ allprim, Point[pts]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Together with the original Voronoi diagram:

```
Show[vm, gr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To obtain a `MeshRegion` from the bounded Voronoi diagram we simply do the following:

```
reg = DiscretizeGraphics @ RegionPlot @ allreg
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can check that it is indeed a `MeshRegion`:

```
{MeshRegionQ[reg], Head[reg]}
```

> {True, MeshRegion}

**Update**

Here is a simplified approach thanks to @J.M.:

```
SeedRandom["blah"]; pts = RandomReal[1, {50, 2}];
cm = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts];
ch = MeshPrimitives[cm, 2][[1]];
DiscretizeGraphics[RegionIntersection[ch, #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]]
```

Comment: As it turns out, generating the bounded Voronoi diagram can be done quite compactly: `ch = MeshPrimitives[cm, 2][[1]]; DiscretizeGraphics[RegionIntersection[ch, #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]]`

Comment: @J.M. That's a better approach. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: I'm okay with you editing your answer to show the simplification. :)

Comment: @J.M. Done. :) ${}$