# Creating Voronoi Mesh Region Bounded by Convex Hull (Possible problem with DiscretizeGraphics)

Tags: mesh, computational-geometry, discretization

I want to create a MeshRegion that is VoronoiMesh bounded by the associated ConvexHullMesh. I followed the procedure in the answer for [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111755/making-a-voronoi-diagram-bounded-by-the-convex-hull), but the resulting MeshRegion is very wrong.

This is what my VoronoiMesh and ConvexHullMesh look like:
[image]

My desire is to have a MeshRegion of only the area of the VoronoiMesh outlined in red. I followed the code example given in the post I linked above:

```
cm = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
ch = MeshPrimitives[cm, 2][[1]];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts];
DiscretizeGraphics[RegionIntersection[ch, #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]]
```

But this code produces the following result, usually...

[image]

I say "usually", because if I execute the same code repeatedly, every so often it will return this:

[image]

Which is exactly what I want! But if I run the same code again, it starts returning the messed up mesh all over again.

Is this a bug in the DiscretizeGraphics function? Is there some way to force it to preserve the Voronoi Cells?

Edit: Per request, the `pts` array.

```
pts={{0, 1.2438972614940857},{0, 0.9636875567529508},{0, 0.8225803919688134},{0, 0.7331683530782342},{0, 0.6697636516843404},{0, 0.621660423493867},{0, 0.5834791607160031},{0, 0.5521750801894381},{0, 0.5258755396778766},{0, 0.503355706442203},{0, 0.48377548219861094},{0, 0.466536436368803},{0, 0.45119892374060755},{0, 0.43743155261595146},{0, 0.424979049640617},{0.40341098865872727, 1.2438972614940857},{0.19715420497821629, 0.9636875567529508},{0.12006445981523653, 0.8225803919688134},{0.08212050964280186, 0.7331683530782342},{0.060356953228638974, 0.6697636516843404},{0.046587915896771304, 0.621660423493867},{0.0372599696436135, 0.5834791607160031},{0.030613294892946417, 0.5521750801894381},{0.025689538419132386, 0.5258755396778766},{0.021927896295954766, 0.503355706442203},{0.018981141802975915, 0.48377548219861094},{0.016624266804637206, 0.466536436368803},{0.014705881752657036, 0.45119892374060755},{0.013120867272804126, 0.43743155261595146},{0.011794246773185007, 0.424979049640617},{0.1141139564736296, 1.055368189826202},{0.0530330848801975, 0.4177262245371366},{0.030242010479031564, 0.22651105945647884},{0.01940636797710833, 0.1433290355141969},{0.013449151385547397, 0.09943176705071363},{0.009839341521273401, 0.07332661224428688},{0.007493690057701841, 0.05648423519099168},{0.0058870837983598205, 0.04495479970632894},{0.0047404626160789665, 0.03669862257794525},{0.0038946423004167724, 0.030573142103318948},{0.00325355735008812, 0.025896568309477543},{0.0027565088483396017, 0.02224094520339375},{0.0023636512876428115, 0.019326274418946333},{0.002047970466101388, 0.016962908952657334},{0.0017906382342701035, 0.015018572254201145},{0.03489248974145652, 0.2903012797360848},{0.019324838289647896, 0.1265437771907919},{0.012302490995349531, 0.06988972730031659},{0.008535217100858894, 0.04401390363286231},{0.0062778121647453404, 0.030135071213654857},{0.0048169455945446405, 0.021863594776775144},{0.0038163905986524577, 0.01655198031239352},{0.00310059081533189, 0.012945694082926644},{0.0025705130959543286, 0.010389159515215744},{0.002166801374764703, 0.008513212629188511},{0.0018520994615352727, 0.007097327135107546},{0.0016019316391343431, 0.00600330527064082},{0.0013997111167807707, 0.005141038929909376},{0.0012338698645754046, 0.004449780505717137},{0.0010961379852522184, 0.003887391498126782},{0.015820808928586148, 0.10328654672879056},{0.01000921582518309, 0.05415604526990609},{0.00699827746735632, 0.03340973888528694},{0.005216702054007623, 0.022709634389713303},{0.004065876243066826, 0.01646437213356673},{0.0032746169962278807, 0.012498327209336324},{0.00270456003800711, 0.009820341814810604},{0.0022786801291417524, 0.00792571457066499},{0.0019511364644942534, 0.006535184160489869},{0.0016931646995521621, 0.005483925761159057},{0.0014859225238663455, 0.004669497716848316},{0.0013166189845158608, 0.00402547699355619},{0.001176305978520755, 0.003507245368741902},{0.0010585607312054211, 0.003083919717300501},{0.0009586694586583974, 0.002733566498891702},{0.007468259413584087, 0.045102310193744596},{0.005467111240200174, 0.027563795078613097},{0.0042654305944460754, 0.01895107354629903},{0.003470784068930911, 0.014004722315624765},{0.0029097308304887512, 0.01086706803143234},{0.002494344903452149, 0.008734689974476137},{0.002175526371727223, 0.007210159206752012},{0.0019238061697594067, 0.0060770072520880125},{0.0017204790239930007, 0.005208444099178768},{0.001553128223754225, 0.004525858863449971},{0.0014132037113772247, 0.003978227422733865},{0.0012946351436568693, 0.0035311586794299185},{0.0011929995796185397, 0.003160728216274545},{0.0011050019153798433, 0.0028498394397423825},{0.0010281394354921568, 0.0025859889021257933},{0.007468259413584087, 0},{0.0054671112402001724, 0},{0.0042654305944460754, 0},{0.003470784068930911, 0},{0.0029097308304887512, 0},{0.002494344903452149, 0},{0.002175526371727223, 0},{0.0019238061697594067, 0},{0.0017204790239930007, 0},{0.001553128223754225, 0},{0.0014132037113772247, 0},{0.0012946351436568693, 0},{0.0011929995796185397, 0},{0.0011050019153798433, 0},{0.0010281394354921568, 0},{1, 2},{0, 0}};
```

Comment: Could you provide the data for `pts`? I can't reproduce this issue using my own points.

Comment: Edited the original post and added the `pts` array at the end.

Comment: You added a boundary-conditions tag - how do boundary conditions come into play here? Could you elaborate on that a bit please.

Comment: I'm using the Voronoi Mesh to perform Natural Neighbor Interpolation, and it doesn't work outside the Convex Hull nor in unbounded cells. The Convex Hull is defined by the boundary conditions of the system I am interpolating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's going on, but I can provide a workaround.

First, I notice if I just discretize the first 99 cells, I get the desired result 1 out of 3 times. Strange.

```
ints = RegionIntersection[ch, #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vm, 2];

Table[{DiscretizeGraphics[ints], DiscretizeGraphics[ints[[1 ;; 99]]]}, 100] // Tally
```

[image]

To workaround this we can construct the `MeshRegion` manually by joining the vertices and constructing the cell indices.

```
coords = ints[[All, 1]];

runs = Partition[Accumulate[Prepend[Length /@ coords, 0]], 2, 1];

MeshRegion[Join @@ coords, Polygon[Range[#1 + 1, #2] & @@@ runs]]
```

[image]

Comment: This works really well and, most importantly, consistently! Thank you so much!