# How can find the 2D Voronoi cell area distribution?

Tags: distributions, computational-geometry

I need to find the area distribution function of the 2D Voronoi cells in *Mathematica* version 11 and later. My old instructions for *Mathematica* 9 don't work anymore. How can I do it?

Comment: If you were to provide your old instructions, we might be able to fix them.

Answer (score 9):

Crossposted and much more extended discussion here (see comments):

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1620190

I think it is a `GammaDistribution` and we can show it, see also [this paper by Tanemura](http://www.scipress.org/journals/forma/pdf/1804/18040221.pdf).

@C.E.'s answer is a good start, but without **careful** consideration, it might yield wrong stats. To gather **good statistics**, let's build a "large", 5000 cells `VoronoiMesh` within a unit `Disk`:

```
pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 5000];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, Axes -> True]
```

We see the stats are obviously offset by the presence of "border" cells of much larger area than regular inner cells have.

[image]

Let's exclude large cells by selecting only those within original region of random points distribution - unit `Disk`:

```
vor=MeshPrimitives[mesh,2];
vor//Length
```

> 5000

```
vorInner=Select[vor,RegionWithin[Disk[],#]&];
vorInner//Length
```

> 4782

We got fewer elements of course and they all are nice regular cells:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Gray], vorInner}]
```

[image]

Now you can see that there is a minimum of distribution at zero area. Close to zero-area cells of course are not present much with the finite number of points per region (or finite density). So there is some prevalent finite mean area there.

```
areas = Area /@ vorInner;
hist = Histogram[areas, Automatic, "PDF", PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

You can find a very close simple analytic distribution:

```
dis=FindDistribution[areas]
```

> GammaDistribution[3.3458431368450587,0.00018456010158014188]

which matches very nicely the empirical histogram:

```
Show[hist, Plot[PDF[dis, x], {x, 0, .0015}]]
```

[image]

And now it is easy to find thing like:

```
{Mean[dis], Variance[dis], Kurtosis[dis]}
```

> {0.0006175091492073445`, 1.1396755130437449`*^-7, 4.793269963533813`}

```
Probability[x > .0005, x \[Distributed] dis]
```

> 0.5740480899719699`

Comment: i used to avoid Histogram preferring BinCounts, in this way i could obtain a table and then his fit. is there a possibility to determine the values of the bars?

Answer (score 7):

First compute the Voronoi mesh:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {25, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then compute the areas of the mesh primitives (`MeshPrimitives` yields a polygon for each Voronoi region):

```
areas = Area /@ MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];
Histogram[areas]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Decreasing effect of unbounded cells

As Vitaliy pointed out in his answer, there are unbounded cells in the Voronoi diagram. For example like this:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}]
VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, it works well to adjust the bounding box:

```
VoronoiMesh[pts, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

More generally, we might create a bounded Voronoi diagram with the methods described in [Making a Voronoi diagram bounded by the convex hull](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111755/731).

### Removing unbounded cells

Chip provided a way, in a comment here below, to remove unbounded cells. Note that some of the unusually large cells are bounded and will be kept.

```
(* Chip's code for finding the points belonging to unbounded cells. *)
toRemove = MeshCoordinates[RegionBoundary[DelaunayMesh[pts]]];
```

We can now find the area distribution of the remaining cells like this:

```
sel = Select[
   MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2],
   Not@*Or @@ RegionMember[#, toRemove] &
   ];
Area /@ sel
```

We can inspect the remaining polygons like this:

```
colors = RandomColor[Length[sel]];
Show[
 Graphics@Riffle[colors, sel],
 Graphics[{Red, Point[toRemove]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: We can also query for the cell areas via `PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]`.

Comment: This could give wrong stats, C.E. and @ChipHurst. I posted a bit different version.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks, good observation. Now if only there was a simple way of selecting the unbounded elements and removing them... (Something to do with the boundary mesh?)

Comment: @C.E. I believe the unbounded cells correspond to the nodes that lie on the boundary of the convex hull.

Comment: In fact to avoid the issue of collinear points, we can take the nodes to be from the Delaunay triangulation: `MeshCoordinates[RegionBoundary[DelaunayMesh[pts]]];`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks, I posted a method based on this idea.

Comment: `RegionBoundary[DelaunayMesh[pts]]` is just `RegionBoundary[ConvexHullMesh[pts]]`, no? (Presumably, getting the convex hull takes less effort than a full triangulation.)

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Mathematically yes, but there are contrived examples due to machine precision. For example `Tally[Table[
  Length[MeshCoordinates[
    ConvexHullMesh[{{0, -1}, {0, 0}, {1, Sqrt[2]}, {#, # Sqrt[2]} &@
       RandomReal[{1, 3}]}]]], 1000]]`

Comment: @C.E. Note that the ones ‘we’d like to remove’ have finite area and should stay.

Comment: @ChipHurst I thought about that, but they are considerably larger than the other ones. Consider e.g. [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xUEti.png). It could skew statistics like the mean. Also, Vitaliy removed all such cells in his answer. But I changed the sentence to be clearer.