# How to find the MeshConnectivityGraph[] from a list of independent cell mesh regions?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, regions, mesh, computational-geometry

I'm generating a bunch of points inside a `BoundaryMeshRegion`. Then I generate the Voronoi mesh of the points, and take the intersection of the Voronoi cells into the region. How could I recover the adjacency of the resulting cells? The problem is that at the end I end up with a list of independent mesh cell regions, so I don't know how could I get the adjacency of the cells from the list.

What I'm doing below.

Take the following binary image:

```
myImage =
```

[image]

Get the mesh region:

```
myMeshRegion = ImageMesh[myImage]
```

[image]

Generate a bunch of points inside such region:

```
myPoints = RandomPoint[myMeshRegion, 100];
Show[{myMeshRegion, Graphics[Point[myPoints]]}]
```

[image]

Get the Voronoi mesh from the points:

```
myVoronoi = VoronoiMesh[myPoints]
```

[image]

Get the intersection of `myMeshRegion` and the cells in `myVoronoi`, using the method in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31187/cropping-a-voronoi-diagram?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
myIntersectionCells = DeleteCases[
  RegionIntersection[DiscretizeGraphics@#, myMeshRegion] & /@ 
   MeshPrimitives[myVoronoi, 2], _RegionIntersection];
Show[myIntersectionCells]
```

[image]

By inspection, we can see that `myIntersectionCells` is a list of `BoundaryMeshRegion` elements, representing every "cell" in this mesh. So, from `myIntersectionCells`, can I get the [MeshConnectivityGraph[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshConnectivityGraph.html)? Related to this question, how could I make `myIntersectionCells` a single mesh, instead of a list of mesh cells?

Thanks

P.S. I'm using MMA 12.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is surprisingly cumbersome. Even if one first converts all the `Boundary MeshRegion` s, then `RegionUnion` (which was my first guess) creates just a `MeshRegion` with only the boundary of the geometry stored as a single polygon.

The following should work however. First we extract all the polygons in `myIntersectionCells`. Then we concatenate all the point lists (in the given order!) and generate a new list `allpolygons` of the polygon index lists, and hand these over to `MeshRegion`. The latter is (hopefully) clever enough to deal with duplicate vertices.

```
allprimitives = (Join @@ (MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & /@ myIntersectionCells))[[All, 1]];
allpts = Join @@ allprimitives;
lengths = Length /@ allprimitives;
allpolygons = Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[Total[lengths]], lengths];

meshregion = MeshRegion[allpts, Polygon[allpolygons]]
```

[image]

Afterwards, you should be able to apply

```
MeshConnectivityGraph[ meshregion, 2]
```

I have only version 12.0, so I have to simulate `MeshConnectivityGraph` with with the help of the [IGraphM package](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM):

```
Needs["IGraphM `"]
IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[meshregion, 2]
```

[image]

I seem to obtain always connected graphs. So maybe `MeshConnectivityGraph` is a bit buggy. It would not be the first region-related function whose first version is buggy...

**Update**

One can generate `myIntersectionCells` a bit faster (5 times as fast on my machine) by using the following piece of code:

```
myIntersectionCells =
  With[{R = MeshPrimitives[myMeshRegion, 2][[1]]},
   Map[
    BoundaryMeshRegion[
      Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[{R, #}]] &,
    MeshPrimitives[myVoronoi, 2]
    ]
   ];
```

It is still orders of magnitude slower than it could be.

Comment: @kglr Ah, using the cloud is a great idea. Thank you for the edit!

Comment: Very cool, thanks! I've tried it a few times, and it seems that in many cases it generates isolated components. Is this because this particular shape could have cells that span out-and-into the shape? I've tried increasing the point number, which reduces this effect, but ideally it would be cool having a single connected mesh. Even if that would mean adding "additional" points to the seeded.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had made an error in the definition of `allprimitives` because I had falsely assumed that each mesh in `myIntersectionCells` would consists of only a single polygon. I corrected it. Please have a look whether it works better for you now.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I still get isolated nodes in the graph. I'm unsure what's the real reason behind this, but at least this does most of what I intend.

Comment: Maybe `MeshConnectivityGraph` has a bug. See my edit; I showed a workaround there.

Comment: @TumbiSapichu Thank you for the bounty!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to get intersection cells and face connectivity graph:

```
polygons = Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonCombine @ 
    Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[#, 
       MeshPrimitives[myMeshRegion, 2]] & /@ MeshPrimitives[myVoronoi, 2];

Show[myMeshRegion, 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], RandomColor[], #} & /@ polygons], 
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

```
adjm = (1 - IdentityMatrix[Length@polygons]) 
  Outer[Boole @ IntersectingQ[Join @@ #[[1]],Join @@ #2[[1]]] &, polygons, polygons]; 

AdjacencyGraph[adjm, 
 VertexCoordinates -> (RegionCentroid /@ polygons), 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 Prolog -> ({Opacity[.7], EdgeForm[White], RandomColor[], #} & /@ polygons), 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

**Update:** In comparison, using `meshregion` from Henrik's answer with `MeshConnectivityGraph` we miss some connections:

```
MeshConnectivityGraph[meshregion, 2, 
 VertexCoordinates -> (RegionCentroid /@ MeshPrimitives[ meshregion, 2]), 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
 Prolog -> ({Opacity[.7], EdgeForm[White], RandomColor[], #} & /@ 
    MeshPrimitives[ meshregion, 2]), ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Comment: What does Outer[] do? This method is not working well for me, the last part, when creating the adjacency matrix, usually crashes the kernel (I'm using 1000 points). The couple of times it has not crashed, it generates a massive amount of edges between the nodes (half a million from the 1000 nodes, when the other method -as I would expect- generates about 3K edges total).

Comment: I'm using MMA 12.2

Comment: @TumbiSapichu, `Outer` checks if two polygons (possibly with multiple cells)  share a coordinate for every pair polygons to create a binary adjacency matrix. I tried this method mainly to see if we can capture the connections missed by meshregion+MeshConnectivity approach in the original example. `Outer` is essentially a brute force method to compute the face connectivity matrix; and as is it does twice as many comparisons as necessary. Definitely not recommended for large inputs.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe that's why the kernel is crashing. But it's strange that when it does not crash, there are many more extra edges.

Comment: Also, I always get an error for `Graphics\`PolygonUtils\`PolygonCombine @ 
    Graphics\`PolygonUtils\`PolygonIntersection`, how were you able to run this? I have MMA 12.2, maybe a compatibility issue?