# Divide a geometric region by (many) lines

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a shape (e.g., a rectangle, a circle, etc.), how to divide it by $n$ randomly chosen lines. It is trivial to *plot* those lines (see figure below), using code like

```
Graphics[Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[0.8], 
   InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}]]}, {49}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True]
```

But how to extract the (many) regions in the figure? There are some posts doing similar things to an image (https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/388948), but I am not sure how to do that to geometric shapes. Thanks!

[image: random lines]

Comment: In what format would you like to obtain the resulting regions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find symbolic connected components (which are those regions you are asking about) in this case using `CylindricalDecomposition`. This can be a bit of an overkill if your goal is only to visualize these regions between lines, but it is such a useful feature and extends to general semialgebraic sets, and thus I outline this solution and its extensions below.

Below I first construct the rectangle and remove the lines (with rationalized random numbers) from it, splitting it to pieces. After this I compute equations representing these regions, and massage them a bit to make the input more palatable to `CylindricalDecomposition` which can extract the wanted regions using the `"Components"` topological operation. After this I reconstruct implicit regions from the resulting list of equations, discretize them, colour them randomly and show them.

```
RegionDifference[
     Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
     RegionUnion@
      Table[InfiniteLine[Rationalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}], 0]], {49}]] //
    Refine[RegionMember[#, {x, y}], Element[x | y, Reals]] & // 
   CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y}, "Components"] & //
  Map[Style[
     Quiet@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}],
     RandomColor[]] &] // Graphics
```

[image]

This method is not fast for large numbers of lines, but `CylindricalDecomposition` can extract all components for these kind of problems, and the rest of the code visualises all of those which have nonzero area. One could improve this solution by two-colouring the result, but that's a different task.

**EDIT**:

Although planar graphs are four-colourable, these graphs are two-colourable, meaning that only two colours are necessary to paint all regions with shared side with a differing colour. @cvgmt presents a fast method for two-colouring for this specific task using `HalfSpace`s and `RegionSymmetricDifference`, while the code below is more general purpose. (Unfortunately `RegionSymmetricDifference` can suffer from discretization issues, but that's another story - and I have a workaround for a similar problem below.)

Code below constructs symbolically the side-adjacency graph from a list of regions after splitting the region (as above) with a bit of trickery (the odd replacement rule could be replaced with `CylindricalDecomposition[..., "Closure"]`, but that would result more complicated and thus more time-consuming operations down the line), and computes a colouring for it, visualising it in the end.

**NOTE**: Why did I comment out `ParallelMap`? Because apparently `CylindricalDecomposition[..., "Components"]` fails for many, if not all less trivial inputs on older Mathematica versions when parallel kernels are in use. This issue has been fixed in 13.1. You can effectively run this code with `ParallelMap` *once* on a fresh session, but not more than that.

```
With[{basereg = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}],
  lines = 
   Table[InfiniteLine[Rationalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}], 0]], {20}]},
 RegionMember[RegionDifference[basereg, RegionUnion@lines], {x, y}] //
                          Refine[#, Element[x | y, Reals]] & //
            CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y}, "Components"] & //
           Map[ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] &] //
          (# /. {Greater ->
                GreaterEqual, GreaterEqual -> Greater, 
              Less -> LessEqual, LessEqual -> Less}) & //
         Subsets[#, {2}] & //
        (*Parallel*)Map[
          Quiet@
            If[
             RegionDisjoint @@ # || 
              RegionDimension[RegionIntersection @@ #] == 0, 
             Nothing, #] &, #] & //
       Map[Apply@UndirectedEdge] //
       SimpleGraph //
     {(*Parallel*)Map[Quiet@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#] &, VertexList[#](*,
        Method->"FinestGrained"*)],
       FindVertexColoring[#, Lighter@Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 2]]} & //
    Transpose // Map[Apply@Style] //
  Graphics[{#, 
     MeshPrimitives[
      DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[basereg, RegionUnion@lines], 1]}] &]
```

[image]

It is also possible to visualise the graph which was used to generate the colouring:

```
With[{basereg = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}],
  lines = 
   Table[InfiniteLine[Rationalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}], 0]], {8}]},
 With[{g = 
    RegionMember[
             RegionDifference[basereg, RegionUnion@lines], {x, y}] //
                        Refine[#, Element[x | y, Reals]] & //
              CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y}, "Components"] & //
          Map[ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] &] //
         (# /. {Greater -> 
             GreaterEqual, GreaterEqual -> Greater, 
             Less -> LessEqual, LessEqual -> Less}) & //
        Subsets[#, {2}] & //
       (*Parallel*)Map[
         Quiet@
           If[
            RegionDisjoint @@ # || 
             RegionDimension[RegionIntersection @@ #] == 0, 
            Nothing, #] &, #] & //
      Map[Apply@UndirectedEdge] // 
     SimpleGraph[#, VertexShape -> Graphics@Circle[], 
       VertexCoordinates -> (RegionCentroid /@ VertexList[#])] &},
  {(*Parallel*)Map[Quiet@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#] &, VertexList[g](*,Method->
       "FinestGrained"*)],
      FindVertexColoring[g, Lighter@Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 2]]} //
     Transpose // Map[Apply@Style] //
   Show[Graphics[{#, 
       MeshPrimitives[
        DiscretizeRegion@
         RegionIntersection[basereg, RegionUnion@lines], 1]}], g] &]]
```

[image]

One more example with some less random lines:

```
lines = DeleteDuplicates@Join[
    Table[Rationalize[InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, N@{Sin[a], Cos[a]}], 0],
     {a, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/3}],
    Table[
     Rationalize[InfiniteLine[-{1, 1}/2, N@{Sin[a], Cos[a]}], 0],
     {a, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/5}],
    Table[Rationalize[InfiniteLine[{1, 1}/2, N@{Sin[a], Cos[a]}], 0],
     {a, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/7}],
    Table[InfiniteLine[
      Rationalize[RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt[2]]], 0],
      Rationalize[RandomPoint[Circle[]], 0]], {2}]]}
```

[image]

Technically speaking this approach is not limited to rectangles and lines, but can actually handle general semialgebraic sets. The process of getting good renderings and even getting the code to evaluate without running out of memory becomes more finicky in this case, though. For instance one should rationalize numbers at coarser accuracy and some hacks on discretizing implicit regions may be necessary.

Interestingly the hardest problem to work around seems to be discretizing cusps on implicit subregions completely. (This is done purely for visualization purposes.) My hack here is effectively rasterizing them.

Since intersections with `Circle`s can produce non-convex regions (unlike plain `InfiniteLine`s), `RegionCentroid` for `VertexCoordinates` may put the graph vertex outside its region. To hack around this, `RegionCentroid` and its closest corresponding point on the (discretized) region boundary are computed and the local minimum of `SignedRegionDistance` on the line defined by them is searched, starting between these points. This produces reasonably aesthetic results, usually keeping graph edges from intersecting, and generally better than just minimizing `SignedRegionDistance` which can put the point in quite an extreme spot on the region.

```
ClearAll[implicitRegionDiscretize];
implicitRegionDiscretize[reg_ImplicitRegion, 
  bbox : {{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}}, step_] :=
 With[{f = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
     Evaluate[
      Boole@
       Refine[RegionMember[reg, {x, y}], Element[x | y, Reals]]],
     CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
       "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}, 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
     CompilationTarget -> "C"]},
  ImageMesh[Image@Table[f[x, y],
     {y, Reverse@Subdivide[N@y1, y2, Max[200, Round[(y2 - y1)/step]]]},
     {x, Subdivide[N@x1, x2, Max[200, Round[(x2 - x1)/step]]]}],
   Method -> "LinearSeparable", DataRange -> bbox]]

With[{basereg = RegionSymmetricDifference @@ Table[
     Disk[Rationalize[N[{Sin[a], Cos[a]}/2], 1/1000], 1], 
     {a, 0, 5 Pi/3, 2 Pi/3}]},
 With[{lines = DeleteDuplicates@Join[Table[
       Circle[Rationalize[N[{Sin[a], Cos[a]}/2], 1/1000], 1],
       {a, 0, 5 Pi/3, 2 Pi/3}],
      Table[
       InfiniteLine[
        Rationalize[RandomPoint[basereg], 1/1000],
        Rationalize[RandomPoint[Circle[]], 1/1000]], {10}],
      Table[Circle[
        Rationalize[RandomPoint[basereg], 1/1000],
        Rationalize[RandomReal[{1/4, 1/2}], 1/1000]], {10}]],
   bbox = RegionBounds@basereg}, 
  With[{g = 
     RegionMember[
                RegionDifference[basereg, RegionUnion@lines], {x, y}] //
               Refine[#, Element[x | y, Reals]] & //
              CylindricalDecomposition[#, {x, y}, "Components"] & //
             Map[ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y}] &] //
            (# /. {Greater -> GreaterEqual,
                 GreaterEqual -> Greater, Less -> LessEqual, 
                LessEqual -> Less}) & //
           Subsets[#, {2}] & //
          ParallelMap[
            Quiet@
              If[
               RegionDisjoint @@ # || 
                RegionDimension[RegionIntersection @@ #] == 0, 
               Sequence @@ #, #] &, #, Method -> "FinestGrained"] & //
         Replace[#, {l_List :> UndirectedEdge @@ l, 
            r_ImplicitRegion :> UndirectedEdge[r, r]}, {1}] & //
           SimpleGraph // 
       VertexReplace[#, 
         Rule @@@ 
          Transpose@{VertexList[#], 
            ParallelMap[
             implicitRegionDiscretize[#, RegionBounds@#, 1/1000] &, 
             VertexList[#], Method -> "FinestGrained"]}] & //
      Graph[#, VertexShape -> Graphics@Circle[],
        VertexCoordinates ->(*Parallel*)Map[
          With[{a = RegionCentroid@#},
            With[{b = RegionNearest[RegionBoundary@#, a]}, 
             a + c (b - a) /. 
              Last@
               Quiet@
                FindMinimum[
                 SignedRegionDistance[#, a + c (b - a)], {c, 1/2}, 
                 Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]]] &,
          VertexList[#]]] &},
   {VertexList[g], 
       FindVertexColoring[g, 
        Lighter@Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 2]]} //
      Transpose // Map[Apply@Style] //
    Show[
      Graphics[{#, 
        MeshPrimitives[
         DiscretizeRegion[
          RegionIntersection[basereg, RegionUnion@lines], bbox, 
          MaxCellMeasure -> 1/10000, MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"], 
         1]}], g] &]]]
```

[image]

Just to prove that this also applies to a general-purpose colouring solution, use parameters below (produce a four-colouring):

$$\cdots$$

```
With[{basereg = Disk[]},
 With[{
   lines = {Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, 2/3],
     Sequence @@ Table[
       Line[
        Rationalize[# {Sin@a, Cos@a} & /@ {1.9999/3, 1.0001}, 
         1/10000]],
       {a, 0, 5 Pi/3, 2 Pi/3}]},
   bbox = RegionBounds@basereg},
```

$$\cdots$$

```
{VertexList[g], 
  FindVertexColoring[g, Lighter@Take[ColorData[97, "ColorList"], 4]]}  //
```

$$\cdots$$

[image]

Comment: Hello, I tried using this cylindrical decomposition to find squares in a finite grid in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275375/86543) but it gave the error shown in the edit of that question. This method did not really answer that question as it seems this method relies on the presence of infinite lines for `RegionDifference` to find the region between the lines as a boolean region but I could use it in another scenario where the grid is more regular.

Comment: @userrandrand Based on your question edits, I assume you got the error message sorted out? If I understood correctly rationalisation of coordinated did the trick for you. It may be that topological operations with `CylindricalDecompose` don't give the most helpful error messages. Nonetheless, `CylindricalDecompose` should be given only equations with exact coefficients (which is accomplished with `Rationalize[..., 0]`.

Comment: Hi sorry yes I forgot to delete this comment. Thanks (:.

Answer (score 15):

### Edit

- Combine several methods which from

[WindingCount](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/298503/72111)

[RegionUnion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275381/72111)

[VertexCoordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/298206/72111)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
graphics = 
  Graphics[
   Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[0.8], 
     InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}]]}, {49}], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True];
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[graphics];
lines = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1];
reg = Join[
    MeshPrimitives[
     BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]], 1], 
    lines] // RegionUnion;
g = Graph[MeshPrimitives[reg, 1] /. Line -> Apply@UndirectedEdge, 
   VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[reg]];
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
faces = Select[faces, WindingCount[Line@#, Mean@#] == 1 &];
Graphics[{{RandomColor[], Polygon@#} & /@ faces}]
```

[image]

- We also add the `DualPlanarGraph`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[123];
lines = Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[0.8], 
    InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}]]}, {49}];
graphics = Graphics[lines, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[graphics];
lines = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1];
reg = Join[
    MeshPrimitives[
     BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]], 1], 
    lines] // RegionUnion;
g = Graph[MeshPrimitives[reg, 1] /. Line -> Apply@UndirectedEdge, 
   VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[reg]];
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
index = FirstPosition[WindingCount[Line@#, Mean@#] & /@ faces, -1];
faces2 = Delete[faces, index // First];
graphics2 = Graphics[{{RandomColor[], Polygon@#} & /@ faces2}];
dual = Graph[VertexList@DualPlanarGraph[g], 
   EdgeList@DualPlanarGraph[g], 
   VertexCoordinates -> RegionCentroid@*Polygon /@ faces, 
   EdgeStyle -> White, VertexStyle -> White, 
   VertexSize -> 12];
dual2 = VertexDelete[dual, VertexList[dual][[First@index]]];
Show[graphics2, dual2]
```

[image]

- **Use `ImageMesh`.**

```
lines = Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[.5], 
    Table[{InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}]]}, {49}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> False];
regs = ConnectedMeshComponents[
   ImageMesh[lines, Method -> "MarchingSquares"]];
MapIndexed[{{EdgeForm[ColorData[97] @@ #2], 
     FaceForm[ColorData[97] @@ #2], #1}} &, regs] // Graphics

{color = RandomColor[], FaceForm[color], EdgeForm[color], #} & /@ 
  regs // Graphics

(*MapIndexed[{{ColorData[97] @@ #2, #1}, 
    Text[ToString @@ #2, RegionCentroid@#1]} &, regs] // Graphics *)
```

[image]

[image]

- **RegionSymmetricDifference**

Thanks at  @kirma some hints about another way.

```
Fold[RegionSymmetricDifference, 
 Table[RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
   HalfSpace[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], RandomPoint@Circle[]]], {50}]]
```

[image]

- **Animation**

```
reg = Fold[RegionSymmetricDifference, 
   Table[RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
     HalfSpace[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], RandomPoint@Circle[]]], {50}]];
DynamicModule[{n = {1, 1}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic@n, 
  Dynamic@Graphics[{RegionSymmetricDifference[reg, 
      RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
       HalfSpace[n, {0, 0}]]], {AbsolutePointSize[10], Red, 
      Dynamic[Arrow[{{0, 0}, .2 n/Norm[n]}]]}, LightGreen, Thick, 
     InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, Cross@n}]}, PlotRange -> 1], 
  Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

- **Use `PolygonDecomposition`.**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
rega = Fold[RegionSymmetricDifference, 
   Table[RegionIntersection[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], 
     HalfSpace[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], RandomPoint@Circle[]]], {49}]];
regb = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], rega];
regadecom = PolygonDecomposition[rega, "Convex"];
regbdecom = PolygonDecomposition[regb, "Convex"];
Graphics[{{{Lighter@RandomColor[], #} & /@ 
    regadecom}, {MapIndexed[{Text[Style[ToString @@ #2, 8], 
       RegionCentroid@#1]} &, regbdecom]}}]
```

[image]

- **Use `even-odd filling rule`.**

I want to find a faster way to generate the 2-colors  region for large amount of lines(for example 400 lines),up to today only a part of work accomplish since  some bugs need to be fixed.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the (vector) image containing the random lines is rasterized first, the result is then subject to connected component analysis. Due to the finite resolution introduced by the rasterization, the approach only works for a few lines--unless the image is made huge?

Comment: @Taozi  You are right. We can adjust the `AbsoluteThickness[1]` to make the lines thin and then we can seperate the regions although there many lines.

Comment: For images you can do two-colour plot like this: `Fold[ImageDifference, ParallelTable[RegionImage[HalfSpace[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], RandomPoint@Circle[]], {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {100}]]`

Comment: @kirma Thanks your code.

Comment: `PolygonDecomposition` seems like a hidden gem similarly to `CylindricalDecomposition` with the somewhat recently introduced topological operations. Too bad it doesn't extend to higher dimensions though...

Answer (score 11):

Another approach:

```
m = Graphics[
  Table[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[0.8], 
    InfiniteLine[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 2}]]}, {49}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Discretize it first:

```
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[m];
```

Get internal lines and lines that defined boundaries:

```
blines = 
  Line[Tuples[
     RegionBounds[
      mesh]][[FindShortestTour[Tuples[RegionBounds[mesh]]][[2]]]]];
lines = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 1];
```

Split lines:

```
res = Region`Mesh`SplitIntersectingSegments[{lines, blines}];
segments = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort /@ Flatten[Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, res[[2]]], 1]];
coords = res[[1]];
```

Construct planar graphs:

```
g = Graph[Range[Length[coords]], UndirectedEdge @@@ segments, 
  VertexCoordinates -> coords, VertexStyle -> Black, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", VertexSize -> Tiny]
```

[image]

Find planar faces (need to filter out the outer face):

```
faces = DeleteCases[PlanarFaceList[g], 
   x_ /; NegativelyOrientedPoints[coords[[x[[;; 3]]]]], 1];

Length[faces]
```

> 873

```
Show[{Graphics[
   GraphicsComplex[
    coords, {Opacity[.7], 
     Thread[{RandomColor[Length[faces]], Polygon /@ faces}]}], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], m}]
```

[image]

To split other shapes like a disk:

```
Show[{Graphics[Disk[]], m}]
```

[image]

```
disk = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Disk[]];
blines = MeshPrimitives[disk, 1];
res = Region`Mesh`SplitIntersectingSegments[{lines, blines}];

segments = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort /@ Flatten[Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, res[[2]]], 1]];
coords = res[[1]];

mf = RegionMember[disk];
segments = Select[segments, (And @@ mf[coords[[#]]]) &];

g = IndexGraph@First[
  ConnectedGraphComponents@
   Graph[Range[Length[coords]], UndirectedEdge @@@ segments, 
    VertexCoordinates -> coords, VertexStyle -> Black, 
    VertexShapeFunction -> "Point", VertexSize -> Tiny]]
```

[image]

```
coords = GraphEmbedding[g];
faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
max = Max[Length /@ faces];
faces = Select[PlanarFaceList[g], (Length[#] != max) &];

Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  coords, {EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[.7], 
   Thread[{RandomColor[Length[faces]], Polygon /@ faces}]}]]
```

[image]

Another shape example:

[image]

```
Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  coords, {EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[.7], 
   Thread[{RandomColor[Length[faces]], Polygon /@ faces}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Do you know if there's any documentation on ``Region`Mesh`SplitIntersectingSegments``? I can't seem to find any and it sounds like a very useful function.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion no it's a undocumented function.

Comment: Ah that's too bad, how can you know about these types of functions?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion well.. something like this  ``Names["Region`Mesh`*Intersect*"]``

Comment: (+1)  This method is powerful!

Answer (score 8):

The following is a bit of a shot in the dark, since I am not sure that I understand what format you would like as output. But it's pretty :-)

```
region = Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh@RandomPoint[region, 20];
primitives = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];
cellsWithin = RegionIntersection[#, region] & /@ primitives;

RegionPlot[
  Evaluate@cellsWithin,
  PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1]
]
```

[image: ellipse tessellated in color]

`cellsWithin` is a list of `BooleanRegion`s that represent the single cells into which your region has been "partitioned".

With thanks to [@Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) who provided [the inspiration code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31198/27951).

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, your method is based on the Voronoi partition of n given random points, which differs from the posted problem. For example, many lines in your figure fail to cut regions along their direction.

Comment: @Taozi That's true. However I think it would help if you specified in your question in what format you would like to obtain your results.

Comment: I think a list of regions should work. This format is easy for visualization and analysis. Now it seems to me that the only way is to start with a list containing the original shape, then iteratively partition the regions in the list. I don't know how to code this, but as the length of the list grows with time, I guess it won't be extremely efficient when there are many lines. I cannot think of smart ways.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best I could come up with. As input I expect a list of 'lines' where a line is a list of the form `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}`. The output is a list of all the different regions where a region is something that is accepted by the `Region[]` object. The algorithm works by keeping a list of regions. It then loops of over all lines and for each line it loops over all regions and splits them in two. It then adds those new pieces to the region list (discarding the old ones).

First define the following function

```
getRegions[startingRegion_, lines_] := 
 Module[{regions, tempRegions, region1, region2},
  regions = {startingRegion};
  Do[
   tempRegions = regions;
   regions = {};
   Do[
    region1 = 
     RegionIntersection[HalfPlane[line, Cross[line[[1]] - line[[2]]]],
       region];
    region2 = 
     RegionIntersection[
      HalfPlane[line, -Cross[line[[1]] - line[[2]]]], region];
    If[! (region1 === EmptyRegion[2]), AppendTo[regions, region1]];
    If[! (region2 === EmptyRegion[2]), AppendTo[regions, region2]];
    , {region, tempRegions}]
   , {line, lines}];
  regions
  ]
```

Then evaluate the following

```
window = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}];
nlines = 3;
linePts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nlines, 2, 2}];
regions = getRegions[window, linePts];

Show @@ (RegionPlot[#, PlotRange -> 1, 
     PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[.4]}] & /@ regions)
RegionPlot[#, PlotRange -> 1, 
   PlotStyle -> {Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[.4]}] & /@ regions
```

which gives

[image]
[image]

Note that for `nlines = 30` it already takes about 16 seconds to evaluate so be careful with large numbers.

Comment: I think this is sort of a equivalent to the `CylindricalDecomposition[..., "Components"]` in my answer. With it you don't need to implement your own algorithm...

Comment: @kirma Yes it's quite a bit faster than my answer. Using built-in function is generally good idea if you know about them.

Comment: I believe `CylindricalDecomposition`/`GroebnerBasis` functions are/were quite a pride of WRI at some point. Of course the point here is that it doesn't work just with linear inequalities but with semialgebraic sets in general. (Thus you can find exact solutions also with disks etc., without uncertainty.) `"Components"` (and other operation forms) is somewhat recent development, and in my opinion should have more visibility.