# Cut out circle out of circle

Tags: graphics

In the [documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0b0kmp0l66m-jqzu2y) of `FilledCurve`, one can create a circle "cut-out" of a bigger circle using `FilledCurve` and `Beziercurve`. Is it also possible using two `Circle` commands and some Boolean operator, as can be done with Adobe Illustrator using the [Pathfinder](http://sites.duke.edu/oit-mps/2010/12/14/using-the-pathfinder-tool-in-adobe-illustrator/) commands? Does some counterpart exist in *Mathematica*?

Edit: As asked in the comments: there exist a few Pathfinder operations, the most kwown are

- Add two graphics
- Substract one graphic from the oterh
- Union of two graphics
- "Exclusive" union of two graphics (without intersection)
- Intersection of two graphics

Thanks for all inputs!

Comment: I don't think so, but you can make your own `circle` based on Bezier curves and use that.

Comment: There is a problem with `Circle` or `Disc` and one way I can think of would be to use image processing functions. As showed here: [intersecting graphics](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/528/5478), about `Polygon`s I highly recommend `PolygonIntersection` which is also described there. At the end there is IMTEK MM suplement introduced by Szabolcs in the same Q&A which might be something what you need.

Comment: In the November 2011 video referenced in the linked question in Kuba's comment above, Chris Carlson refers to the forthcoming Mathematica version 9 release as containing "polygon boolean operations, differences, unions, intersections, and so forth ...". So there's a possibility that in version 10 there may be a debugged and reliable set of geometry Boolean functions... :)

Comment: If they are concentric, use the `Annulus` primitive; will be faster in terms of performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps `Disk` is more appropriate than `Circle`, if you want it to be filled:

```
Graphics[{Black, Disk[{0, 0}, 3], White, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}]
```

[image]

I don't think this works the same way as pathfinder, but it is getting at similar effects. One of the main reasons for using pathfinder is that it joins the multiple paths together in order to create a single object that is easy to manipulate. In *Mathematica* it might be more common to give the object a name and then use that name whenever you wish to reproduce, move, or modify the object.

As an example with circles (rather than disks), consider:

```
doubleCircle[{x_, y_}] := {Black, Circle[{x, y}, 3], Circle[{x, y}, 2]}
```

which creates a ``double circle'' function. You can draw lots of such objects:

```
rand = RandomInteger[{1, 15}, {5, 2}]
Graphics[doubleCircle[#] & /@ rand]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use region functionality and do boolean operations, e.g. (borrowing from bills):

```
annulus[c_, r1_, r2_] := RegionDifference[Disk[c, r1], Disk[c, r2]]
fun[] := Module[{rand}, rand = RandomInteger[{1, 15}, {5, 2}];
  RegionPlot[RegionUnion @@ (annulus[#, 3, 2] & /@ rand), 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Yellow}, Background -> Black, 
   Frame -> None, PlotRange -> {{-5, 20}, {-5, 20}}, 
   PlotPoints -> 40]]
```

The following animation is made from `tab=Table[fun[],20]`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can control the thickness in this way.

```
Graphics[{Thickness[#], Circle[{0, 0}, 3]}] & /@ {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
ListAnimate@Table[
  RegionPlot[
   RegionUnion @@ (Annulus[#, {3.2, 5}] & /@ 
      RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {5, 2}])
   , AspectRatio -> Automatic
   , PlotStyle -> Red
   , BoundaryStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[4], Yellow}
   , Background -> Black
   , Frame -> None
   , PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-15, 15}}
   , PlotPoints -> 40
   ]
  , {i, 1, 10, 1}
  ]
```

[image]